# How to get form data as a object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried `jQuery('#form_id').serialize()`. This returns only the form data as a url encoded string. Is it possible to get the form data as an object?

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 106):

Have you tried "serializeArray"? That gives you an array of names and values. You could turn that into an object if you wanted to:

```
var paramObj = {};
$.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
  paramObj[kv.name] = kv.value;
});
```

(I'll have to check again to see what jQuery does with arrays; I *think* it encodes them as Javascript array values, but I'm not 100% sure.)

**edit** ah no, it doesn't set up multi-valued parameters as arrays - you get repeats of the same name. Thus, the make-an-object code should look like this:

```
var paramObj = {};
$.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
  if (paramObj.hasOwnProperty(kv.name)) {
    paramObj[kv.name] = $.makeArray(paramObj[kv.name]);
    paramObj[kv.name].push(kv.value);
  }
  else {
    paramObj[kv.name] = kv.value;
  }
});
```

(or something like that; could probably be squeezed a little.)

Comment: alternative: http://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Answer (score 34):

You may take a look at the [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function:

```
$('#form_id').serializeArray()
```

Comment: this returns a serialized array instead of an object.