# How to use Lodash to merge two collections based on a key?

Tags: javascript, collections, merge, lodash

I have two collections, and the objects have a common key "userId". As below:

```
var _= require('lodash');

var a = [
  { userId:"p1", item:1},
  { userId:"p2", item:2},
  { userId:"p3", item:4}
];

var b = [
  { userId:"p1", profile:1},
  { userId:"p2", profile:2}
];
```

I want to merge them based on "userId" to produce:

```
[ { userId: 'p1', item: 1, profile: 1 },
  { userId: 'p2', item: 2, profile:2 },
  { userId: 'p3', item: 4 } ]
```

I have these so far:

```
var u = _.uniq(_.union(a, b), false, _.property('userId'));
```

Which result in:

```
[ { userId: 'p1', item: 1 },
  { userId: 'p2', item: 2 },
  { userId: 'p3', item: 4 },
  { userId: 'p1', profile: 1 },
  { userId: 'p2', profile: 2 } ]
```

How can I merge them now?

I tried _.keyBy but it results in:

```
{ p1: { userId: 'p1', profile: 1 },
  p2: { userId: 'p2', profile: 2 },
  p3: { userId: 'p3', item: 4 } }
```

which is wrong.

What's the last step I should do?

Answer (score 61):

Second highest voted answer doesn't do proper merge. If second array contains an unique property, it is not taken into account.

This approach does a proper merge.

### Lodash

```js
var a = [
  { userId:"p1", item:1},
  { userId:"p2", item:2},
  { userId:"p3", item:4}
];

var b = [
  { userId:"p1", profile:1},
  { userId:"p2", profile:2},
  { userId:"p4", profile:4}
];
var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(a, 'userId'), _.keyBy(b, 'userId'));
var values = _.values(merged);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### ES6+

```js
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749873/80766
const mergeDeep = (target, ...sources) => {
  if (!sources.length) return target;
  const source = sources.shift();

  if (target instanceof Object && source instanceof Object) {
    for (const key in source) {
      if (source[key] instanceof Object) {
        if (!target[key]) Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
        mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    }
  }

  return mergeDeep(target, ...sources);
}

const a = [
  { userId:"p1", item:1},
  { userId:"p2", item:2},
  { userId:"p3", item:4}
];

const b = [
  { userId:"p1", profile:1},
  { userId:"p2", profile:2},
  { userId:"p4", profile:4}
];


const aKeyed = a.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur.userId]: cur }), {});
const bKeyed = b.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur.userId]: cur }), {});
const merged = mergeDeep(aKeyed, bKeyed);
const values = Object.values(merged);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: This may not suit all scenarios, if `userId` field is not unique per collection the data is compressed into a single object.

Comment: @karloluis Then use a field that's unique?

Answer (score 43):

You can use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map), [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) and [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs#find).

```
// Iterate over first array of objects
_.map(a, function(obj) {

    // add the properties from second array matching the userID
    // to the object from first array and return the updated object
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(b, {userId: obj.userId}));
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pbzkn5nz/)

```js
var a = [{
    userId: "p1",
    item: 1
}, {
    userId: "p2",
    item: 2
}, {
    userId: "p3",
    item: 4
}];

var b = [{
    userId: "p1",
    profile: 1
}, {
    userId: "p2",
    profile: 2
}];

var arrResult = _.map(a, function(obj) {
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(b, {
        userId: obj.userId
    }));
});

console.log(arrResult);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arrResult, 0, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.1.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Just a thought, if the second list contains a unique userId this won't be added to the final list. I suspect this is a behaviour OP doesn't want.

Comment: These functions are now available in latest version of JS. `a.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, b.find(user => obj.userId === user.userId)))`

Answer (score 9):

Lodash has a `merge` method that works on objects (objects with the same key are merged). In this demo, the arrays `a` and `b` are first converted into objects (where `userId` is the key), then merged, and the result converted back to an array (`_.values`) (getting rid of the keys). `_.flatten` is then necessary because `_.values` adds an extra level of array.

```
var u= _({}) // Start with an empty object
  .merge(
    _(a).groupBy("userId").value(),
    _(b).groupBy("userId").value()
  )
  .values()
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness: A proposal without any library.

```js
function merge(a, b, key) {

    function x(a) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            if (!(b[key] in obj)) {
                obj[b[key]] = obj[b[key]] || {};
                array.push(obj[b[key]]);
            }
            Object.keys(b).forEach(function (k) {
                obj[b[key]][k] = b[k];
            });
        });
    }

    var array = [],
        obj = {};

    x(a);
    x(b);
    return array;
}

var a = [
        { userId: "p1", item: 1 },
        { userId: "p2", item: 2 },
        { userId: "p3", item: 4 }
    ],
    b = [
        { userId: "p1", profile: 1 },
        { userId: "p2", profile: 2 }
    ],
    c = merge(a, b, 'userId');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 4):

ES6+ version without lodash.

```js
 const array1 = [{ userId: "p1", item: 1 },  { userId: "p2", item: 2 },{ userId: "p3", item: 4 }];
const array2 = [{ userId: "p1", profile: 1 }, { userId: "p2", profile: 2 }];


const result = array1.map(a => ({
  ...a,
  ...array2.find(b => b.userId === a.userId) // _.find(array2, 'skuId') <-- or with lodash 
}));

 document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxqjtL9b/)

```
var a = [{
    userId: "p1",
    item: 1
}, {
    userId: "p2",
    item: 2
}, {
    userId: "p3",
    item: 4
}];

var b = [{
    userId: "p1",
    profile: 1
}, {
    userId: "p2",
    profile: 2
}];

a.forEach(function (aitem) {
    b.forEach(function (bitem) {
        if(aitem.userId === bitem.userId) {
            _.assign(aitem, bitem);
        }
    });
});

console.log(a);
```