# JS Fetch JSON parse is modifying object

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I've come across this weird behavior from fetch.

First look at this screenshot of the lengths (which are correct) and actual structures: [console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqFn.png)

Consider the following json response from a server, where the `likes` array clearly contains one object, and the `comments` array contains two:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "payload":{
        "272699880986":{
            "likes":[
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:21.000Z",
                    "senderId":10209615042475034,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo Re",
                    "likes":1
                }
            ],
            "comments":[
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:54.000Z",
                    "senderId":1021426764639564,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo J. Re",
                    "comments":1
                },
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:24.000Z",
                    "senderId":10209615042475034,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo Re",
                    "comments":1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, passing that response through the whole `response.json()`, like this:

```
fetch('http://example.com/entries.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        ...authKeys,
    }
})
.then(response => {
    switch(response.status){
        case 200:
            console.log('status 200', response)
            return response.json()
    }
})
.then(json => {
    console.log('parsed response')
    console.log(json)
})
```

Gets me the following result:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "payload":{
        "272699880986":{
            "likes":[
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:54.000Z",
                    "senderId":1021426764639564,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo J. Re",
                    "likes": 1,
                    "comments":1
                },
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:24.000Z",
                    "senderId":10209615042475034,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo Re",
                    "comments":1
                }
            ],
            "comments":[
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:54.000Z",
                    "senderId":1021426764639564,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo J. Re",
                    "comments":1
                },
                {
                    "createdTime":"2016-11-07T04:41:24.000Z",
                    "senderId":10209615042475034,
                    "senderName":"Alfredo Re",
                    "comments":1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

See how it mixed up the `likes` and `comments` collections. This is driving me insane right now. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Here's [a gif showing chrome's console](http://g.recordit.co/pC9OlOO3X9.gif) listing showing and array containing one object, and another one containing two objects. When I click the former, it turns into an array with two objects! This baffles me

Comment: what response do you see in the developer tools network tab for that `fetch` - in other words, the actual response from your server

Comment: @JaromandaX the actual response is the first piece of code at the question

Comment: You realise that the GIF, the screenshot, the JSBin and the code you've put in your question all seem to differ? It's difficult to help because we cannot reproduce the issue you're experiencing, and you can't reproduce the issue in a publicly viewable demo for us.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm actually having a hard time trying to isolate the issue in a publicly available way. The same code I've put in jsbin produces different (and weird) results inside my app, so that probably means it's something else about my code. I'll keep removing stuff from the app and update the question as soon as I find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out it was actually lodash's `_.merge()` mutating my objects way after fetching them. I was using lodash to merge the two collections (likes and comments) based on the `senderId` key.

Just for the record, I ended up using this method instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094948/1418038