# Merge Javascript Objects WITH Same Key AND Include Duplicate Values WHERE Key Matches

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I am trying to merge some JSON data sets BY key value WHILE including duplicate values WHERE the key matches.

I have tried this quite a bit now but can't seem to produce the object that I need.

**Object 1**

```
[
  {"userId":"1",
   "email":"email1@gmail.com"
  },
  {"userId":"2",
   "email":"email2@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

**Object 2**

```
[
  {"id":"1abc",
   "listingId":"4def",
   "userId":"2"
  },
  {"id":"2abc",
   "listingId":"2def",
   "userId":"1"
  },
  {"id":"3abc",
   "listingId":"3def",
   "userId":"2"
  }
]
```

I need to merge these objects in a way that looks like this:

**Desired Output**

```
[
  {"id":"1abc",
   "listingId":"4def",
   "userId":"2",
   "email":"email2@gmail.com"
  },
  {"id":"2abc",
   "listingId":"2def",
   "userId":"1",
   "email":"email1@gmail.com"
  },
  {"id":"3abc",
   "listingId":"3def",
   "userId":"2",
   "email":"email2@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

**Problems I am Experiencing**

I am able to merge the data sets successfully using a function that looks like this:

```
function merge(a, b, key) {

    function x(a) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            if (!(b[key] in obj)) {
                obj[b[key]] = obj[b[key]] || {};
                array.push(obj[b[key]]);
            }
            Object.keys(b).forEach(function (k) {
                obj[b[key]][k] = b[k];
            });
        });
    }

    var array = [],
        obj = {};

    x(a);
    x(b);
    return array;
}
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094948/1951144*

But it produces results that look like this:

```
[
  {"id":"1abc",
   "listingId":"4def",
   "userId":"2",
   "email":"email2@gmail.com"
  },
  {"id":"2abc",
   "listingId":"2def",
   "userId":"1",
   "email":"email1@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

**Is there a way to use the above function WHILE keeping AND including the duplicate values where my keys match?**

Answer (score 3):

For each element in arr2, create a new element containing the props of the item from arr2, and the email of the corresponding entry in arr1.

```js
let arr1 = [
  {"userId":"1",
   "email":"email1@gmail.com"
  },
  {"userId":"2",
   "email":"email2@gmail.com"
  }
];

let arr2 = [
  {"id":"1abc",
   "listingId":"4def",
   "userId":"2"
  },
  {"id":"2abc",
   "listingId":"2def",
   "userId":"1"
  },
  {"id":"3abc",
   "listingId":"3def",
   "userId":"2"
  }
];

let output = arr2.map(a2 => ({...a2, email: arr1.find(a1 => a1.userId === a2.userId)?.email}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked exactly like I needed it too.
And it was just one line.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This solution works even if the key isn't known yet. `.flatMap()` both arrays and pass in the desired key (in example it's `"userId"`). Use `Object.entries()` on each object so they will be an array of pairs.

```
[{A1: A1v}, {A2: A2v},...]
// into
[[A1, A1v], [A2, A2v],...]
```

`.flatMap()` the second array and on each iteration `.flatMap()` the first array. Then compare the given key (`"userID"`) with the key of each object from the second array (`"a"`) AND the value of that key and the value of the key of the object in the first array.

```
a === key && av === bv
```

If both criteria are meet then merge those objects and return it, otherwise...

```
? {...objA, ...objB}
```

return an empty array, which ultimately results to nothing since `.flatMap()` flattens one level of arrays.

```
: []
```

```js
const arrA=[{userId:"1",email:"email1@gmail.com"},{userId:"2",email:"email2@gmail.com"}];const arrB=[{id:"1abc",listingId:"4def",userId:"2"},{id:"2abc",listingId:"2def",userId:"1"},{id:"3abc",listingId:"3def",userId:"2"}];

function masterKey(primary, key, secondary) { 
  let result = secondary.flatMap(objB => Object.entries(objB).flatMap(([b, bv]) =>   
    primary.flatMap(objA => Object.entries(objA).flatMap(([a, av]) =>
      a === key && av === bv ? {...objA, ...objB} : []))));
  return result;
}

console.log(masterKey(arrA, "userId", arrB));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.