# Changing a nested array value based on a given index in a reducer while not mutating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer working with an object with arrays. I want to change a value on the nested arrays based on a given index. This code works but I can't seem to get my test to work using deep freeze. I was trying to look at the redux example here http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html using `.map` to find the index with no luck. Any ideas?

```
export default function myReducer(state = { toDisplay: [] }, action) {
  const { type, groupIndex, itemIndex } = action;
  const newObject = Object.assign({}, state);
  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_GROUP:
      newObject.toDisplay[groupIndex].isSelected = newObject.toDisplay[groupIndex].isSelected ? false : 'selected';
      return newObject;
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_ITEM:
      newObject.toDisplay[groupIndex].values[itemIndex].isSelected = newObject.toDisplay[groupIndex].values[itemIndex].isSelected ? false : true;
      return newObject;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For anyone curious after watching a helpful [redux video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread) I came up with this:

```
export default function myReducer(state = { toDisplay: [] }, action) {
  const { type, groupIndex, itemIndex } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_GROUP:
      return {
        ...state,
        toDisplay: [
          ...state.toDisplay.slice(0, groupIndex),
          {
            ...state.toDisplay[groupIndex],
            isSelected: state.toDisplay[groupIndex].isSelected ? false : 'selected'
          },
          ...state.toDisplay.slice(groupIndex + 1)
        ]
      };
    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        toDisplay: [
          ...state.toDisplay.slice(0, groupIndex),
          {
            ...state.toDisplay[groupIndex],
            values: [
              ...state.toDisplay[groupIndex].values.slice(0, itemIndex),
              {
                ...state.toDisplay[groupIndex].values[itemIndex],
                isSelected: state.toDisplay[groupIndex].values[itemIndex].isSelected ? false : true
              },
              ...state.toDisplay[groupIndex].values.slice(itemIndex + 1)
            ]
          },
          ...state.toDisplay.slice(groupIndex + 1)
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Using a helper/library like suggested is probably the best route but my team wishes to not add another dependency.

Comment: Check React ```update``` utility function: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Comment: Have you thought about using Immutable.js? Right off the bat, it seems as though it could be helpful for what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @RafaelQuintanilha - I was hoping to avoid adding another dependency if possible. But I'm open to it if it's really necessary. I couldn't seem to find any examples show casing solutions similar to the problem I have now for either of those. I may just not understand the libraries enough yet however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `Object.assign(...)` only does a shallow copy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/deep-object-merging-in-es6-es7).

As you have objects nested inside arrays nested inside objects I would highly recommend the [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) from react (as mentioned by Rafael). These allow you to do something like this:

```
case actionTypes.TOGGLE_GROUP:
  return update(state, {
    toDisplay: {
      [groupIndex]: {
        isSelected: {$set: newObject.toDisplay[groupIndex].isSelected ? false : 'selected'}
      }
    }
  });
```

If you are looking to modify a simple value inside an array with raw js then you can use something like this:

```
return list
  .slice(0,index)
  .concat([list[index] + 1])
  .concat(list.slice(index + 1));
```

([source](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread))

Comment: Thank you. That egghead video was especially enlightening.