# Object.assign vs $.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an immutable object and want to **clone** or **copy** this object in order to make changes to it.

I have always been using the built-in `Object.assign()` and recently stumbled upon the jQuery's [`$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

I was wondering, What is the better way to do this, and what exactly the difference is between both?

Looking at the documentation, I cannot seem to really find a notable difference concerning why to choose either one.

Comment: Well.. for `$.extend` you need to have jQuery available. So the one difference is that one of them depend on an external library. If you already have jQuery in your project this point is kinda moot - but including an entire library just so that you can use one `$.extend` function doesn't seem like such a good idea.

Comment: I do have JQuery in my project, is there no difference between both then? Even when using arrays for example?

Comment: This post should be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: I would accept if you post the first as an answer. otherwise I suppose this question can be closed.

Comment: no need to duplicate content :-) just upvote the answer that helped you most

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: It's often overlooked that many library features exist because the native functionality didn't at that point.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The two key differences are the optional boolean for `deep` merge which is recursive on the jQuery `$.extend` method (where `false` is not supported?!) ...

```
let object1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: {
    forename: 'John',
    surname: 'McClane'
  },
};

let object2 = {
  id: 2,
  name: {
  }
};

// merge objects
let objExtend = $.extend(true, {}, object1, object2);
let objAssign = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);

// diff
console.log(objExtend.name.forename); // "John"
console.log(objAssign.name.forename); //  undefined
```

> Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

**Example**: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ku54jn1/)

The second is the `$.extend` method ignores `undefined` ...

```
let object1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'hello world'
};

let object2 = {
  id: 2,
  name: undefined
};

// merge objects
let objExtend = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
let objAssign = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);

// diff
console.log(objExtend.name); // "hello world"
console.log(objAssign.name); //  undefined
```

**Example**: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78qn6a9y/)

### Docs

**MDN**:    [Object.assign(target, ...sources)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

**jQuery**: [jQuery.extend([deep], target, object1 [, objectN])](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

### Additionally:

If you are looking for a way to deep merge objects *without* jQuery, this answer is excellent:

[How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

**Example**: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o59s01az/1/)

How to deep merge using `Object.assign` with ES6:

```
function isObject(item) {
  return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

function mergeDeep(target, ...sources) {
  if (!sources.length) return target;
  const source = sources.shift();

  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    for (const key in source) {
      if (isObject(source[key])) {
        if (!target[key]) Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
        mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    }
  }
  return mergeDeep(target, ...sources);
}
```

Comment: Should mention another important difference - unlike `Object.assign`, jQuery ignores `undefined` fields in source objects.

Comment: @riv thanks, I have now updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: *IMPORTANT* Hey guys, don't forget about the prototype. Prototype is not copied in Object.assign, but copied over in Jquery.extend