# Object.assign—override nested property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an Object `a` like that:

```
const a = {
  user: {
   …
   groups: […]
   …
  }
}
```

whereby there are a lot more properties in `a.user`

And I would like to change only the `a.user.groups` value. If I do this:

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {
  user: {
    groups: {}
  }
});
```

`b` doesn't have any other Property except `b.user.groups`, all others are deleted. Is there any ES6 way to only change the nested property, without loosing all the other, with `Object.assign`?

Comment: imo it looks to be doing what `Object.assign` is supposed to. It's changing the `user` property with the new object you provided. If it's the only thing you want to change why don't you simply do `b.user.groups = /* value */`?

Comment: You might be interested by the [assign-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assign-deep) or the [object-assign-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign-deep) packages.

Comment: Refs this question about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge

Answer (score 146, accepted):

After some trying I could find a solution that looks pretty nice like that:

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {
  user: {
    ...a.user,
    groups: 'some changed value'
  }
});
```

To make that answer more complete here a tiny note:

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a)
```

is essentially the same as:

```
const b = { ...a }
```

since it just copies all the properties of `a` (`...a`) to a new Object. So the above can written as:

```
 const b = {
   ...a,          //copy everything from a
   user: {        //override the user property
      ...a.user,  //same sane: copy the everything from a.user
      groups: 'some changes value'  //override a.user.group
   }
 }
```

Comment: I upvoted because of explaining well and using syntaxic sugar :) Just passing by, if you want to return an array with a new element inside, it's basically the same mechanism : [ ...someArray, newElement ].

Comment: I must say, exactly what I was looking for and it did the job perfectly.

Comment: Object.assign and spread operator are not exactly the same. Spread operator doesn't copy the prototype while Object.assign does

Answer (score 18):

Here's a small function called `Object_assign` (just replace the `.` with a `_` if you need nested assigning)

The function sets all target values by either pasting the source value in there directly, or by recursively calling `Object_assign` again when both the target value and source value are non-`null` objects.

```js
const target = {
  a: { x: 0 },
  b: { y: { m: 0, n: 1      } },
  c: { z: { i: 0, j: 1      } },
  d: null
}

const source1 = {
  a: {},
  b: { y: {       n: 0      } },
  e: null
}

const source2 = {
  c: { z: {            k: 2 } },
  d: {}
}

function Object_assign (target, ...sources) {
  sources.forEach(source => {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
      const s_val = source[key]
      const t_val = target[key]
      target[key] = t_val && s_val && typeof t_val === 'object' && typeof s_val === 'object'
                  ? Object_assign(t_val, s_val)
                  : s_val
    })
  })
  return target
}

console.log(Object_assign(Object.create(target), source1, source2))
```

Comment: It works like a charm. my case was the following : I have set up a custom property  on a nested object of my root one. This property only exists on the front-side for a graphical enhancement purpose. Then, when I execute an action from my root object that call the back-end I used Object.assign to refresh my root object with data sent by the server. Unfortunately my custom property on the nested object was 'deleted'. Thanks to your function it's not the case anymore.

Comment: hmm I found a use case that totally mess your algorithm : my backend handles a list where items are sorted by  'creationDate desc'. So when from my front-end end I ask the back-end to add a new element into my list, when the server sends me back data, the item previously indexed at position '0' is now indexed at position '1' (and so on...). Due to this index shifting, your algorithm corrupts all my data model :(

Comment: @stephanebrun Oof. You shouldn't ever assume objects fields keep their order. Yes, their order is _deterministic_, but there is no "clean/minimal" way of guaranteeing it. If you need to have the values be logically indexed, you should have the keys be their index. Other options would be using arrays or maps. The fastest (not so clean) way I can think of right now, would be to cache all the keys as they come, then create the resulting object according to that order again.

Comment: yes I think indexing objects with their keys will solve the problem. Anyway your algorithm is great. I keep it. It's just I have a weird case and I'm trying to find a solution that work for all the cases. But I think it is just (easily) impossible. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8):

You asked specifically for an ES6 way with Object.assign, but maybe someone else will prefer my more 'general' answer - you can do it easily with lodash, and personally I think that this solution is more readable.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
_.set(a, 'user.groups', newGroupsValue);
```

It mutates object.

Comment: Well of course, that's why I assumed that you would not like to use my solution but someone else with similar problem might find it useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can change it this way,

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {
  user: Object.assign({}, a.user, {
          groups: {}
        })
});
```

Comment: do not mutate `b.user.groups`, `user` is shared across b and a!

Comment: [Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone) to the docs describing what @borovsky mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

assign method will make a new object by copying from the source object, the issue if you  change any method later on in the source object it will not be reflected to the new object.

Use create()

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

```
const b = Object.create(a)
b.user.groups = {}
// if you don't want the prototype link add this
// b.prototype = Object.prototype
```

This way you have b linked to a via the prototype and if you make any changes in a it will be reflected in b, and any changes in b will not affect a

Comment: That is indeed an interesting point, but in this case I need to create a copy of the source.

Comment: Then your own answer is what you are looking for

Comment: Or use create() and then do.   b.prototype = Object.prototype

Answer (score 4):

More general solution below. It makes recursively assigning only if there are conflicts (same key names). It resolves issues assigning complex objects, which has many reference points.
For example, `nested-object-assign`, an existing package for nested object assign in npm, stuck with complex objects assign because it recursively goes through all keys.

```js
var objecttarget = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: {x:2,y:{k:1,l:1},z:{j:3,l:4}},
  c: false,
  targetonly: true
};

var objectsource = {
  a: 'somestring else',
  b: {k:1,x:2,y:{k:2,p:1},z:{}},
  c: true,
  sourceonly: true
};

function nestedassign(target, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(sourcekey=>{
    if (Object.keys(source).find(targetkey=>targetkey===sourcekey) !== undefined && typeof source[sourcekey] === "object") {
      target[sourcekey]=nestedassign(target[sourcekey],source[sourcekey]);
    } else {
      target[sourcekey]=source[sourcekey];
    }
  });
  return target;
}

// It will lose objecttarget.b.y.l and objecttarget.b.z
console.log(Object.assign(Object.create(objecttarget),objectsource));

// Improved object assign
console.log(nestedassign(Object.create(objecttarget),objectsource));
```

Comment: Good one, only this line:

`if (Object.keys(` **source** `).find( targetkey =>...`

should start with 

`if (Object.keys(` **target** `).find( targetkey =>`

Comment: @sicko Thanks for the feedback but you're wrong. If you change like that, you'll lose values that are only existed in source. Result is based on target. That's why iteration is based on source to add them to target even they are not existed in target. I added objecttarget.targetonly and objectsource.sourceonly in snippet. Try change code like you pointed. You'll see that result doesn't have sourceonly key and value.

Comment: Please see my answer for the correct NestedObjectAssign(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71174859/5173064.
If I use your function and my arguments (created to really test the function) then your function throws error.
BTW, the first part of your if will always be true:
 Object.keys(source).forEach(sourcekey=>{
    if (Object.keys(source).find(targetkey=>targetkey===sourcekey) !== undefined

Answer (score 3):

A working version which **supports nested Arrays** as well

```
const target = {
   var1: "...",
   var2: {
       nestVar1: "...",
       nestVar2: [...]   
       }
}

const source = {
  var2: {
      nestVar3: { ... }
      nestVar4: "...",
      nestVar5: [...]
      },
  var3: "...",
  var4: [...]
}
```

the Function:

```
function objectAssign(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(sourceKey => {
      if(Object.keys(source).find(targetKey => targetKey === sourceKey) !== undefined && typeof source[sourceKey] === "object") {
        target[sourceKey] = objectAssign(target[sourceKey], source[sourceKey]);
      } else if(!Array.isArray(source)) {
        target[sourceKey] = source[sourceKey];
      } else {
        target = source;
      }
    });
    return target;
}
```

then

```
let newObj = objectAssign({}, target, source);
```

Answer (score 2):

Small fine tune of phillips first answer.

```
const object1 = {
  abc: {
    a: 1
  }
};

const object2 = {
  abc: {
    b: 2
  }
};

Object.assign(object1, {
    abc: {
        ...object1.abc,
        ...object2.abc
    }
});

console.log(object1);
// Object { abc: Object { a: 1, b: 2 } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my NestedObjectAssign() contribution, because I have seen a function being duplicated across posts, and it does not work good.

This version just works as expected, as shown in example:

```js
function NestedObjectAssign(target, source) 
{
    Object.keys(source).forEach(sourceKey => 
    {
        if (typeof source[sourceKey] === "object") 
        {
            target[sourceKey] = NestedObjectAssign(target[sourceKey] || {}, source[sourceKey])
        }
        else 
        {
            target[sourceKey] = source[sourceKey]
        }
    })

    return target
}

var target = 
{
    stringTarget: "target",
    stringCommon: "targetCommon",
    nestedCommon: 
    {
        target: 1,
        common: 1,
        nestedTarget: 
        {
            target: 1,
            common: 1
        }
    }
}

var source = 
{
    stringSource: "source",
    stringCommon: "sourceCommon",
    nestedCommon: 
    {
        source: 2,
        common: 3,
        nestedSource: 
        {
            source: 2,
            common: 3
        }
    }
}

var t = NestedObjectAssign({}, target)
var s = NestedObjectAssign({}, source)
var targetSource = NestedObjectAssign(t, s)

console.log({ target })
console.log({ source })
console.log({ targetSource })
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old question & there are many answers, but for future developers that will see this question there is a more straightforward solution for this issue: we'll need to convert custom objects into JSON objects.

**Solution:**

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(YourCustomObjectHere));
```

This will string your custom object into JSON and then reparse it into JSON object.

I hope this answer helps all developers stuck in this issue & thanks

Comment: That is nothing but a »poor mans deep clone«, not talking about performance at all, this will only work as expected if the object you pass in is completely serializable to json. That doesn't inlcude functions, classes, Dates, Class Instances that utilize the prototype chain and much more.

Comment: Thanks, I've just noticed that I was only needed it to store it in Firebase Firestore so I didn't noticed that the functions are not assigned to the class after parsing it from the JSON string

Answer (score -1):

Here is the nestedAssign() with unlimited number of sources.
It's improved answer based on answers by **sicko** and **zEn feeLo**.
Intentionally used legacy ES5 syntax, but if you need ES6, it can be shortened by arrow function (=>).

```
window.nestedAssign = function(target, source) { // it accepts multiple sources, unlimited number of arguments. "source" is just initialization of variable.
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        if (source = arguments[i]) {
            Object.keys(source).forEach(function(sourceKey) {
                if ("object" === typeof source[sourceKey]) { // important to check this first, before array
                    target[sourceKey] = nestedAssign(target[sourceKey] || {}, source[sourceKey]);

                }else if (Array.isArray(source)) { // we could skip it, if we don't expect nested arrays, but ok.
                    target = source;

                }else {
                    target[sourceKey] = source[sourceKey];
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```