# JavaScript object merging, keep properties misisng in overwriting objects

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I've following scenario where I'm merging two object using `Object.assign` function

```
Object.assign(
    {}, 
    {
        a:1, 
        b: {
            c:{
                d: 1, 
                e: 1
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        a:2, 
        b: {
            c: {
                d:2
            }
        }
    }
);
```

and getting

```
{
    a: 2,
    b: {
        c: {
            d: 2
        }
    }
}
```

but I am expecting to get

```
{
    a: 2,
    b: {
        c: {
            d: 2,
            e: 1
        }
    }
}
```

I.e., `e` should not be eliminated. I want to retain properties in `source1` hierarchy that are absent in `source2` object hierarchy. Am I using `Object.assign` in wrong way?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes I stumbled upon that question and figured it was more than a year old. So is "No it doesn't" still the answer to merging objects?

Comment: Actually this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34749873/2219831) to the same question worked for me

Comment: Yeah, the ES6 spec hasn't changed in that time, so it's still not built in.  But yes, always look beyond the accepted answer - there's quite a few fairly upvoted answers on that question.