# Merge object with Object.assign override internal object without merge

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two object that I want to **merge** in a new object, the first object is for default options for a google chart:

```
optionsA = {
    height: 500,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    hAxis: {
      showTextEvery: 0,
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45,
      format: 'date',
    },
}
```

With my second object I want to add some properties to `hAxis` and override present options with the new values but I want to keep the options by default in **`optionsA`**.

This is my second object:

```
optionsA = {
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      },
      format: 'percent',
    },
}
```

*These objects are more complex but I reduce the properties to simplify the question*

When I try to merge with object.assign the result is that object B add new root properties to the new object, but properties in `hAxis` is complete overrided with the options in `optionsB`.

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, optionsA, optionsB);
```

This is the object that I want expected:

```
{
    height: 500,
    focusTarget: 'category',    
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
         count: 10
      },
      format: 'percent',
      showTextEvery: 0,
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45,
    },
}
```

but instead of this I am getting this:

```
{
    height: 500,
    focusTarget: 'category',    
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
       gridlines: {
         count: 10
       },
       format: 'percent',
    },
}
```

Properties in hAxis are completely override with the new properties, what's wrong with my aproach?

Comment: `Object.assign()` only operates on the top-level properties of the source objects. It does not "descend" into sub-objects.

Comment: Refer to this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge

Comment: `Object.assign({}, optionsA, optionsB, {hAxis: Object.assign({}, optionsA.hAxis, optionsB.hAxis)})` should do it

Answer (score 3):

If the nesting is not deep, you can break the merge process in two steps like below:

```js
optionsA = {
    height: 500,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    hAxis: {
      showTextEvery: 0,
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45,
      format: 'date',
    }
};

optionsB = {
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      },
      format: 'percent',
    }
};

let newNestedMerged = Object.assign({},optionsA.hAxis, optionsB.hAxis);
optionsA.hAxis = newNestedMerged;
optionsB.hAxis = newNestedMerged;
let newObj =  Object.assign(optionsA, optionsB);
console.log(newObj);
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the same property in both object.

> The properties are overwritten by other objects that have the same
>   properties later in the parameters order.

Let see the example of [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects_with_same_properties) in MDN.

My proposal is merge the same properties first.

```js
optionsA = {
    height: 500,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    hAxis: {
      showTextEvery: 0,
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45,
      format: 'date',
    },
}
optionsB = {
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      },
      format: 'percent',
    },
}
Object.assign(optionsA.hAxis, optionsB.hAxis);
let newObj = Object.assign({}, optionsB, optionsA);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Good aproach but not work for me, This is a simple example of the object, actually there are a lot of properties that I need to merge.

Comment: Yeah, I think here is the thing you are looking for. Hope that helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/4886453

Comment: Thanks @tai-le you save my day!

Comment: Cool :) Glad to know. If it's helpful for you. Lets accept it :)

Comment: Sorry @tai-le but is the answer in your comment that actually help me., Object .assign merge only root properties and this doesn't work for me