# Get Value Key pair from Firebase with Node.js function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

Ok, I am using Algolia for handling search within my app. The following code adds whatever is in my database to my Algolia Index. However, whenever the data is imported, all of the values in a firebase node get placed under "text" in the Algolia Index.

How can make it to where it is stored as the key value pair found in Firebase.

**i.e.**

address: 1234 Main St.

***VS. / (Instead of)***

text:

address: 1234 Main St.

---

My Code:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database
  .ref('/blog-posts/{blogid}/text')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME);
    const firebaseObject = {
      text: event.data.val(),
      objectID: event.params.blogid,
    };
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are missing here, is the pushing of the data to Algolia. What you can do if you want to have all the firebase data in an object, is assigning it to a new object, as well as the `objectID`

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database
  .ref('/blog-posts/{blogid}/text')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME);
    const firebaseObject = Object.assign({}, event.data.val(), {
      objectID: event.params.blogid,
    });
    index.saveObject(firebaseObject); // .then or .catch as well
  });
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I do have that afterward. return index.saveObject(firebaseObject).then(
      () => event.data.adminRef.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(
          Date.parse(event.timestamp)));
});  I updated my question with a picture that shows what happens and what I need to happen.

Comment: Your code is different though, did you notice the object.assign?

Comment: No, I did not. I'll try this out and see if it works. Sorry about that. And thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Awesome  glad it helped

Comment: How would I sync I child deeper in my Firebase tree with this?

Comment: Either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge or `const fireBaseObj = .val(); firebase.objectID = blogid`