# How to compare through complete JSON and bind it to another JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON which looks like this:-

```
{
    "property" : value,
    "property" : value,
    "subProperty" : {
        "subProperty1" : {
            "subProperty1a" : {
                "property" : value,
                "property" : value
            },
            "subProperty1b" : {
                "property" : ["1", "2"],
                "property" : value
            },
            .....
        },
        "subProperty2" : {
            "subProperty2a" : {
                "property" : value,
                "property" : value
            },
            "subProperty2b" : {
                "property" : value,
                "property" : value
            },
            .....
        },
        "subProperty3" : {
            "subProperty3a" : {
                "property" : value,
                "property" : value
            },
            "subProperty3b" : {
                "property" : value,
                "property" : value
            },
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

This JSON can have any number of fields added later on in any position.What I want is when I add new fields, then I want to compare old JSON with new JSON. If any propert is missing, bind that property with new one.

Right now I am using following code to achieve this:-

```
    scope.tempObj = {};
    scope.findObjectByLabel = function(obj1, obj2, obj3){
                        for(var i in obj1)
                            {
                                obj3[i] = obj2[i];
                                if(obj2[i] == undefined)
                                {
                                    obj3[i] = obj1[i];
                                }
                                if(typeof(obj1[i]) == 'object')
                                {
                                    scope.findObjectByLabel(obj1[i], obj2[i],obj3[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            return obj3;        
                    }

scope.newJSON = scope.findObjectByLabel(scope.newJSON, scope.oldJSON ,scope.tempObj);
```

But the above code can only compare through one level. Can any one suggest me any improvement on the above code so that it can compare through entire JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [`_.merge` polyfill from GitHub by @anvk](https://gist.github.com/anvk/cf5630fab5cde626d42a).

```js
function mergeDeep(out) {
  out = out || {};

  for (var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var obj = arguments[i];

    if (!obj) {
      continue;
    }

    for (var key in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
      }

      // based on https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Object]') {
        out[key] = mergeDeep(out[key], obj[key]);
        continue;
      }

      out[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  return out;
};

var merged = mergeDeep({a: 1}, { b : { c: { d: { e: 12345}}}});  
console.dir(merged); // { a: 1, b: { c: { d: { e: 12345 } } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem , lodash came to the rescue.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

Look at merge & and deep equal (which is called just equal).

Usage example:

```
  //**********//
 // _.merge //
//**********//
 var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }


  //**********//
 // _.equal //
//**********//
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };

_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true

object === other;
// => false
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

To merge two object try like below.

```
function merge(oldObj, newObj){
   for (var prop in newObj) {
     if(typeof newObj[prop] === 'object'){
            merge(oldObj[prop], newObj[prop]);     
     }

     if(typeof newObj[prop] !== 'object')
        oldObj[prop] = newObj[prop];
    }
    return oldObj
}

console.log(merge(oldObj, newObj, oldObjTemp));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8n244fmb/2/

To find the missing properties and values in multiple level.

```
var oldObj = {
     "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
     "title": "Software Engineer",
     "location": {
         "locality": "San Francisco",
         "region": "CA",
         "country": "United States"
     },
     "age": 62,
     "status": "Active"
};
var newObj = {
     "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
     "title": "Software Engineer",
     "location": {
         "locality": "San Francisco",
         "country": "United States"
     },
     "age": 62,
     "company": "Accenture"
};


var missingProps = {};

function getMissingProps(oldObj, newObj){
     for (var prop in oldObj) {
     if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof oldObj[prop] === 'object')
       missingProps = getMissingProps(oldObj[prop], newObj[prop]);
     else if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
         missingProps[prop] =  oldObj[prop] ;
   }

   return missingProps;
}

console.log(getMissingProps(oldObj, newObj));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8n244fmb/

if you want complete missing Json props structure try this

```
var oldObj = oldObjTemp = {
     "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
     "title": "Software Engineer",
     "location": {
         "locality": "San Francisco",
         "region": "CA",
         "country": {"name" : "United States", "code":"US"}
     },
     "age": 62,
     "status": "Active"
};
var newObj = {
     "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
     "title": "Software Engineer",
     "location": {
         "locality": "San Francisco",
         "country": {"name" : "United States"}
     },
     "age": 62,
     "company": "Accenture"
};


var missingProps = {};

function getMissingProps(oldObj, newObj, oldObjTemp){
   for (var prop in oldObj) {
     if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof oldObj[prop] === 'object'){
            getMissingProps(oldObj[prop], newObj[prop], oldObjTemp[prop]);     
     }
     else if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            delete oldObjTemp[prop];
     }
    }
}

getMissingProps(oldObj, newObj, oldObjTemp);

console.log(oldObjTemp);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8n244fmb/1/