# Avoid databinding on nested arrays - vue.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js, variable-assignment

I'm getting headache avoiding databinding on nested arrays.
Let's say i have 2 objects:

- Items, array of all items
- Item, a single item object

I use

```
Object.assign({}, object)
```

to avoid databinding, bit this only works for non-nested array fields.
Example:

```
data: {
    items: [
        {
        name: 'Pencil case',
        contents: [
            {title: "Red Pencil"}, {title: "Blue Pencil"}
            ]
        }, 
      {
        name: 'Rubber container',
        contents: [
            {title: "Yellow Rubber"}, {title: "Green Rubber"}
            ]
        },
    ],

    selected_item: {
      name: 'Pencil case',
      contents: [
        {title: "Red Pencil"}, {title: "Blue Pencil"}
      ]
    }
},
mounted() {
  this.selected_item = Object.assign({}, this.items[0]);
}
```

There's no databinding on name, but there is still binding on contents.title for example. I absolutely need to assign the object absolutely without databinding.

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Razinar/04tLy8z1/4/).
In the first input binding on "title" is real, while in the second input there are no binding on "name" as expected. I can't get over it, help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Comment: If you have jQuery, you can use `$.extend(true, {}, yourObject);`. The first parameter tells it to deep merge instead of shallow merge.

Comment: Thank you so much Phiter. You made my day :)