# How to modify javascript reference object completely

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem:

A library is returning a reference on an object. Now I don‘t want to modify just single parts of the object, I want completely override the object.

My code looks like the following:

```
var options=getOptions();
options=newOptions;
// now do something with the new options.
```

But when I’m running this code, the reference will be removed and a new one will be set.

So how can I copy a whole new object to the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the object you're referring to with `options`, but that has no effect on any reference to the original object the library has. There's **nothing** you can do with the return value of `getOptions` that will replace the object the lib has with an entirely new object; all you can do is change the state of the object it gives you (adding, changing, and/or removing properties).

Unless the library provides you a way to change the object it refers to internally, you can't completely replace that object (without modifying the library).

Here's an example to illustrate:

```js
// Emulating the library:
var lib = (function() {
  var libOptions = {
    name: "original"
  };
  
  return {
    // The operation you said it has
    getOptions: function() {
      return libOptions;
    },
    // The operation it would need to have
    setOptions: function(newOptions) {
      libOptions = newOptions;
    }
  };
})();

var options = lib.getOptions();
options = {
  name: "replaced"
};

console.log(options.name);          // "replaced"
console.log(lib.getOptions().name); // "original"

lib.setOptions(options);

console.log(options.name);          // "replaced"
console.log(lib.getOptions().name); // "replaced"
```

When the library gives you a reference to its object, you have something like this in memory:

```
libOptions−−+
            |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|     (object)     |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            |   | name: "original" |
options−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then when you set `options` to something else:

```
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
libOptions−−−−−>|     (object)     |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | name: "original" |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
options−−−−−−−−>|     (object)     |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | name: "replaced" |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

As you can see, setting `options` doesn't have any effect on the library's reference in `libOptions`.

That's why the lib would have to provide `setOptions`.

Of course, again, you can change the *state* of the object (provided the library isn't giving you a defensive copy or a frozen object);

```
options.name = "updated";
```

which does this:

```
libOptions−−+
            |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|     (object)     |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            |   | name: "updated"  |
options−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to deep copy the object so that original object is intact and you can modify its copy. Correct me if wrong.

```
var options=getOptions();

var copyOfObject = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( options ));
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are getting an object from a library and you want to change some keys while keeping the rest of the object the same.

If it's only a few properties that you want to change, you can just assign the values on the object you recieve form the library:

```js
function getLibObject() {
  return {
    constantKey: 'constant',
    overridenKey: 'to be overriden',
  };
}
var libObject = getLibObject();
libObject.overridenKey = "has been overriden";
libObject.newKey = "A new key has been added";
console.log(JSON.stringify(combinedObject)); //{"constantKey":"constant","overridenKey":"has been overriden","newKey":"A new key has been added"}
```

If the keys in the object you want to change is only one level deep, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a new 'shallow merged' object. (Depending on the browsers you want to support, you may need a polyfill)

```js
function getLibObject() {
  return {
    constantKey: 'constant',
    overridenKey: 'to be overriden',
  };
}
var libObject = getLibObject();
var newOptions = {
  overridenKey: 'has been overriden',
  newKey: 'A new key has been added'
};
var combinedObject = Object.assign({}, libObject, newOptions);
console.log(JSON.stringify(combinedObject)); //{"constantKey":"constant","overridenKey":"has been overriden","newKey":"A new key has been added"}
```

If you want your merge to be deeper than just one level, `Object.assign` won't work. You can use utility functions like [Lodash merge] or use some of the [SO answers which solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```js
function getLibObject() {
  return {
    constantKey: 'constant',
    nestedKey: {
      deepConstantKey: 'This is nested at the second level and should not change',
      deepOverrideKey: 'This is nested at the second level and should be overriden'
    }
  };
}
var libObject = getLibObject();
var newOptions = {
  nestedKey:{
     deepOverrideKey: 'This value has been overriden'
  }
};
var combined = _.merge({}, libObject, newOptions);
console.log(JSON.stringify(combined))
//{"constantKey":"constant","nestedKey":{"deepConstantKey":"This is nested at the second level and should not change","deepOverrideKey":"This value has been overriden"}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help. I understand the problem.

I fixed now the problem in a really dirty way... 
When i have modifikated options i destroy the lib object and create a new one. It’s not the fine way but a solution.