# Javascript simple object override by defaults

Tags: javascript, performance

bsd

I have a simple object which I would like to override with another one, in case some of the properties do not exist in the object, it should be taken from a default preset object, might be deeply nested

Here is an example of the default settings object

```
defaults = {
   name : 'Joe',
   options : {
      color : 'green',
      dates : {
         from : new Date,
         to   : new Date,
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the provided object

```
settings = {
   name : 'David',
   options : {
      color : 'purple'
   }
}
```

Here is the expected result, a combination between the two...

```
final = {
   name : 'David',
   options : {
      color : 'purple',
      dates : {
         from : new Date,
         to   : new Date,
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using any external libraries? I have tried some approaches (`JSON.stringify / parse` / iterating over the objects / etc...) but couldn't get a clean solution... hopefully a oneliner

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Did any of these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work doing it manually setting each value based if defaults have been changed.

```
final = {
      name : settings.name ? settings.name : "Joe",
      options {
        color: settings.color ? settings.color : "green",
        dates: {
          from : settings.dates.from ? settings.dates.from : new Date,
          to: settings.dates.to ? settings.dates.to : new Date
        }
      }
    }
```

This will probably work best:

```
var final = Object.assign({}, default, settings);
```

Comment: Updated answer hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Use this `$.extend(true, {}, defaults,settings)`. Pay attention to the order of json variable. In this case, `settings` will override `defaults` should these two variables have the same attribute.

If you are looking into pure JS answer. Here is the code.

```
function extend(a, b){
    for (var key in b) {
        if (b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
            return a;
        }
    }
}
console.log(extend(defaults,settings));
```

Comment: `jQuery` was not included as the tag so notify in your post that you are using `jQuery` :)

Comment: I see. But OP did say that OP has try using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` has nothing to do with `jQuery`, it's `VanillaJS` functionality. Your answer is correct, just point out that it's using a library :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution.

> To note, the code is quite lengthy due to the nature of `shallow` & `deep` copying of the object.

Using `Object.assign(defaults, settings)`, will merge your objects, but your `date` key will be removed as it performs a **Shallow Copy** of the object.

Below, I have used a snippet I have found on [`How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge) by a user named [`jhildenbiddle`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903063/jhildenbiddle) which performs a `deep` merge of the object and is `immutable` (doesn't edit the original arrays).

---

```js
let defaults = {
  name: 'Joe',
  options: {
    color: 'green',
    dates: {
      from: new Date(),
      to: new Date(),
    }
  }
};

let settings = {
  name: 'David',
  options: {
    color: 'purple'
  }
};

function mergeDeep(...objects) {
  const isObject = obj => obj && typeof obj === 'object';

  return objects.reduce((prev, obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      const pVal = prev[key];
      const oVal = obj[key];

      if (Array.isArray(pVal) && Array.isArray(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = pVal.concat(...oVal);
      } else if (isObject(pVal) && isObject(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = mergeDeep(pVal, oVal);
      } else {
        prev[key] = oVal;
      }
    });

    return prev;
  }, {});
}

let final = mergeDeep(defaults, settings);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with `final = Object.assign(defaults, settings)` is same as `final = defaults = settings` or `defaults = settings; final = defaults;` but if you use

```
Object.assign(settings, defaults, settings)
```

explanation:

`Object.assign` will overwrite value of first parameter with second parameter and extend / overwrite with values of every other succession parameter and it would be equivalent to jQuery `$.extend()`

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
final = Object.assign(defaults, settings)
```

Comment: Date doesn't get assigned.