# Create a pure function to merge objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming

Let's say I have the variables 'state' and 'newState'. I would like to create a pure function that returns 'state' updated with the properties (and sub properties) of 'newState'. Here is an example:

```
const state = {id:1, name:'aName', description: 'aDescription'};

const newState = {id:1, name:'newName', subItems: {id:3, type:'whatever'}};
```

The function would return:

```
{id:1, name:'newName', subItems: {id:3, type:'whatever'}}
```

I could use rest parameters but I don't know how to append as opposed to override. I can't just loop through the properties because I want the function to be pure (redux reducer).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For whatever it is worth the common ES6 pattern you will see `this.setState({...this.state, ...updates})` where updates is any changes. This is really just syntax sugar and is basically Object.assign, but it helps the clarity in my opinion. Take a look at the redux tutorials. What you're asking is basically the essence of redux. https://redux.js.org/api/store. As to your function question: a pure function just means the output is always the same with the same input and the input isn't altered or-> `Object.assign({}, oldObj, newObj)`

Comment: @DanielB.Chapman the weird thing is that when I used the rest/spread syntax and overrides the values of the original object so when I used rest for the example above, it was missing description.

Comment: *"The function would return: { ... }"* – how come `description` is absent in the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

... or [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the 1st argument being an empty object:

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
const state = {id:1, name:'aName', description: 'aDescription'};
const newState = {id:1, name:'newName', subItems: {id:3, type:'whatever'}};

// Example with spread syntax:
const result1 = { ...state, ...newState };

// Example with Object.assign:
// @NOTE: Providing an empty `{}` as the 1st argument,
// ensures you don't mutate `state`.
const result2 = Object.assign({}, state, newState);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

### Side notes:

- Expanding on @user633183's comment, both ways produce a *shallow* merge. They only go 1-level deep. If you're looking to do a *deep* merge, I suggest you check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579540/1814486).
- At the time of writing this, `Object.assign` has better cross-browser support than spread syntax on object literals, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility). While this shouldn't be a problem if you correctly use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or any other transpiler, it is worth mentioning.
- We don't usually refer to functions as immutable (actually they can be since they are values themselves but that's probably not what you mean in the context of your question). Values can be *immutable*, functions can be *pure*; meaning they don't cause *side-effects* such as mutating their arguments.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Just out of curiousity, is there any way to do this using only ES6 rest/spread syntax?

Comment: @Eitan Yup, added an example in my snippet.

Comment: that's how I though it would work. I tried it and it overrides the description but maybe I had a typo. Thanks!

Comment: *"... with the properties (and sub properties)"* – this is a shallow merge

Comment: @user633183 Added that info in the side notes. In fact your comment led me down to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge. This question is more of a duplicate of this one so I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.assign` could be useful to update `state`:

```js
const state = {id:1, name:'aName', description: 'aDescription'};

const newState = {id:1, name:'newName', subItems: {id:3, type:'whatever'}};

Object.assign(state,newState)//<-- updates state

console.log(state)
```

As NicholasKyriakides points out, to create a new object you should add {} in the beginning.

Comment: Oops you just mutated `state` this way. Add an extra empty `{}` as the first argument of `Object.assign` to avoid this, like so: `Object.assign({}, state, newState)`

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Op wants to mutate state I think

Comment: I take it that the statement `I would like to create a pure function...` indicates otherwise.

Comment: what about this `returns 'state' updated` Lol. I don't know, either way op now knows both ways.

Comment: I think it's merely confusion on the part of the OP since both these statements are contradictory, but I could be wrong.