# How to merge nested objects Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = { "1": { "id": 1 }, "2": { "id": 1, "key": "value" } }
let y = { "2": { "id": 2 } }

let z = {
   ...x,
   ...y,
}
 
console.log(z);
```

I would like to have an output of

```
{ "1": { "id": 1 }, "2": { "id": 2, "key": "value" } }
```

the Current output is

```
{ "1": { "id": 1 }, "2": { "id": 2 } }
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It's working perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72080411/6666348

Answer (score 2):

Keys will only be applies the the first level, you must go down a level.

```js
let x = { "1": { "id": 1 }, "2": { "id": 1, "key": "value" } }
let y = { "2": { "id": 2 } }

let z = { ...x, ...y } // outer
for (let k in z) z[k] = { ...x[k], ...y[k] } // inner
console.log(z)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!-- Expected

{
  "1": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "key": "value"
  }
}

-->
```

#### A more robust approach

I borrowed Lewis' example for deep-merging multiple objects and converted it to a plugin.

```js
// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736757/1762224
const ObjectUtils = (() => {
  const { keys, freeze } = Object // sym-links
  let __isObject, __merge, __coalesceByKey, __deepMerge // fwd declaration
  __isObject = a => typeof a === "object" && !Array.isArray(a)
  __merge = (a, b) =>
    __isObject(a) && __isObject(b)
      ? __deepMerge(a, b)
      : __isObject(a) && !__isObject(b)
        ? a : b
  __coalesceByKey = src => (acc, key) =>
    (acc[key] && src[key]
      ? (acc[key] = __merge(acc[key], src[key]))
      : (acc[key] = src[key])) && acc
  __deepMerge = (target, ...sources) =>
    sources.reduce(
      (acc, src) => keys(src).reduce(__coalesceByKey(src), acc), target
    )
  return freeze({ isObject : __isObject, deepMerge : __deepMerge })
})()

let x = { "1": { "id": 1 }, "2": { "id": 1, "key": "value" } }
let y = { "2": { "id": 2 } }

console.log(ObjectUtils.deepMerge({}, x, y));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use lodash:

```
_.merge(object, [sources])
```

> This method is like _.assign except that it recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. Source properties that resolve to undefined are skipped if a destination value exists. Array and plain object properties are merged recursively. Other objects and value types are overridden by assignment. Source objects are applied from left to right. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources.

Comment: Like frodo said, take a look on this https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge. _merge and _mergeWith

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
let x = { "1": { id: 1 }, "2": { id: 1, key: "value" } };
let y = { "2": { id: 2 } };
let z = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(x)) {
  if (y.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    z[key] = {
      ...value,
      id: y[key].id
    };
  } else {
    z[key] = value;
  }
}
console.log(z);
```