# Object recursive merge in ES6 vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript since ES6 offers the spread operator `...` as a convenience to merge, among different structures, objects.
If objects have a property with the same name, then the right-most object property overwrites the previous one. E.g.

```js
    const foo = {
      propA: 'a',
      propShared: 'sharedFoo',
    }
    
    const bar = {
      propB: 'b',
      propShared: 'sharedBar',
    }
    
    const mergedObject = {
        ...foo,
        ...bar
    };
    
    console.log(mergedObject);
```

will print out

```json
{
    propA: 'a',
    propB: 'b',
    propShared: 'sharedBar'
}
```

Now, let's say that I want to recursively apply this pattern to all the properties which may be of type object. E.g. you may have

```js
    const foo = {
      propA: 'a',
      propShared: {
         propX: 'x',
         propShared: {
            prop1: 1
         }
      },
    }
    
    const bar = {
      propB: 'b',
      propShared: {
         propY: 'y',
         propShared: {
            prop2: 2
         }
      },
    }
```

Given the rule above, if I do:

```js
const mergedObject = {
        ...foo,
        ...bar
    };
```

I will completely loose the content from `foo.propShared` and keep `bar.propShared`. So, assuming that the properties are unknown, the only approach that I see is to collect the properties of each object through `Object.keys`, add unique properties to a new Object to be returned, search for properties in common, recurse on the function to create a new Object to be assigned to that property.

Is there any native way to do it or should I write an iterative algorithm as the one I mentioned above? What should be the way to go?

Comment: this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256929/13583510

Comment: I think so. So the answer is: no native approach, you have to implement your algorithm.

Comment: What would your desired output be?

Comment: An approach like: `const merged = Object.assign({}, foo, {
  propB: bar.propB,
  BarPropShared: bar.propShared,
});` would probably be the easiest and most painless given the information I have.

Comment: @Joel  as soon as you know the properties of the object that's the best. Unfortunately it is not my case. I receive a structured group of options (not flat, unfortunately) that I have to merge with another. I'm always concerned with efficiency and I think that native approaches are always the best, but I suspect that I have to implement my own solution or mimic an existing _ad hoc_ implementation like the one reported above by cmgchess