# Inclusive mixin with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mixins

So I want to prevent overriding shared keys, when doing a mixin with JS, so we have:

```
const v = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 4,
      d: 'str'
    }
  }
};


console.log(Object.assign({}, v, {a: {b: {c: 5}}}));
```

this will log:

> { a: { b: { c: 5 } } }

but I am looking for this instead:

> { a: { b: { c: 5, d: 'str' } } }

anyone know how to do this (preferably without a library).

Comment: I was responding when it was marked duplicate :'( Try this: `const a = {}; const object3 = {...a, ...v }`

Comment: This is a duplicate but I think this is more appropriate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge

Comment: FWIW you are trying to deep merge instead of shallow merge.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the dupe, I'd say it's more [How to deep merge instead of shallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Comment: Agreed, I could not find that one (SO really needs to improve search)

Comment: @katie um ... not sure how that is different from the code in the question.

Comment: FWIW it depends really on what you value - brevity or nativeness, this can obviously be written without the use of a 3rd party library, but then a 3rd party library would allow you to write more succinct code e.g. [lodash.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) supports deep merging.

Comment: Hey @JonasWilms ! The `...` will fill in all the missing attributes, so it's not a shallow copy but a deep copy.

Comment: @Katie I don't think the spread technique works, it seems to work the same way Object.assign works.

Comment: @Katie see: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/d83682d73433c79ac2c69339e3672182

Comment: @MrCholo I think I'm confused about the question... the spread technique gets you the result you're looking for ( `{ a: { b: { c: 5, d: 'str' } } }` ) as seen in the gist you made: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/d83682d73433c79ac2c69339e3672182 Is there more to this question that I've missed?

Comment: last time I checked it gives me: `{ a: { b: { c: 4, d: 'str' } } }`, so 4 not 5, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

A fairly naïve solution which cannot handle cycles:

```
const mixin = (a, b) => {

  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(b)) {

    if (typeof val !== 'object') {
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    if (val === null) {
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    mixin(a[key], b[key]);
  }

  return a;

};

const mixinInclusive = (...v) => {
  return v.reduce(mixin, {});
};


console.log(mixinInclusive(v, {a: {b: {c: 5}}}));
```