# Apollo Server v2 - GraphQL resolver not being invoked

Tags: node.js, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-server, express-graphql

I am a newbie to the graphql world and I'm trying to setup multiple modular schemas and resolvers using Apollo Server v2.

I noticed a weird behavior where I have issues with the order of my resolvers. 
In the line `Object.assign({}, propertiesResolver, agreementsResolver)` all resolvers defined by propertiesResolver don't get invoked since it is the first in the order of resolvers. If I swapped the two sets of resolvers like `Object.assign({}, agreementsResolver, propertiesResolver)` now resolvers defined by agreementsResolver don't get invoked.

Am I missing some important detail about graphql execution here?

**Note:** All my schema definitions and corresponding resolvers are correctly defined, I feel something is wrong with the order in which I'm importing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.

`Object.assign` does not do a *deep merge*, which is presumably what you're expecting. If two sources have the same property, only the last source's property will be used. So given two objects like:

```
const a = {
  Query: {
    foo: () => 'FOO',
  },
}
const b = {
  Query: {
    bar: () => 'BAR',
  },
}
```

if you use `Object.assign` to merge them, the resulting object will have a single `Query` property that matches either `a` or `b` (depending on which was the later parameter). In order to do a *deep* merge that combines objects of properties with the same name, you should use an existing solution, like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge):

```
const resolvers = _.merge(a, b)
```

or [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge).

Comment: Aah!! how did I miss that!! Brilliant, thanks!! Do you think JS has anything similar to _.merge() ?

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in the spec and, as far as I'm aware, no future plans to add it. You can import [just the one function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge) or use some other similar library like `deepmerge`. Or write your own, since you only need to go down two levels.