# How can I Embed the Reports Filter in Google Data Studio?

Tags: php, reporting, looker-studio

This is a scenario that I am trying to achieve: I created a report in Google Data Studio and embedded to my website. I activated "any one with link can view" option so that this report will be visible to my website users.

But I need to show my website users different data depending on their user ids. Basically showing a filtered data according to user id. But the challenge that I have here is, these users do not have a google account. Due to this, using a community connector and passing an email id in the config function will not work for me.

I tried the bookmarking option where you embed a link and change a parameter for different users. It will show correctly in embed code. But once user clicks or opens in Google Data Studio, then this filter goes off.

Has anyone implemented a work around for this scenario? Showing different data right from the webapplication in which the graph is embedded.

Showing different data according to user id is so critical for our use case that without it, data studio with its all functions cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, we need to create a custom data source provider.

**Step 1**: We need to write a custom data source to https://script.google.com/. First, edit the Application.json. Here we have to update the manifest JSON and Code.gs script.

For more information https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/JSON-connect/src

**appsscript.json**

```
{
  "dataStudio": {
    "name": "JSON Connect",
    "logoUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/master/JSON-connect/assets/logo.png",
    "company": "Lingewoud",
    "companyUrl": "https://lingewoud.nl/",
    "addonUrl": "https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/JSON-connect/README.md",
    "supportUrl": "https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/issues/new?title=JSON%20Connect%20Connector%20Issue",
    "shortDescription": "Connect to JSON data by URL",
    "description": "Free JSON connector. Fetch data from any JSON data source by URL. Use caching to speed up rendering.",
    "sources": ["CUSTOM_JSON"],
    "authType": ["NONE"],
    "feeType": ["FREE"]
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
//  Copyright notice
//
//  (c) 2019 Gabriël Ramaker <gabriel@lingewoud.nl>, Lingewoud
//
//  All rights reserved
//
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//
//  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!

/* eslint-disable prefer-rest-params */
/* eslint-disable prefer-spread */

/**
 * Throws and logs script exceptions.
 *
 * @param {String} message The exception message
 */
function sendUserError(message) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  cc.newUserError()
    .setText(message)
    .throwException();
}

/**
 * function  `getAuthType()`
 *
 * @returns {Object} `AuthType` used by the connector.
 */
function getAuthType() {
  return {type: 'NONE'};
}

/**
 * function  `isAdminUser()`
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} Currently just returns false. Should return true if the current authenticated user at the time
 *                    of function execution is an admin user of the connector.
 */
function isAdminUser() {
  return false;
}

/**
 * Returns the user configurable options for the connector.
 *
 * Required function for Community Connector.
 *
 * @param   {Object} request  Config request parameters.
 * @returns {Object}          Connector configuration to be displayed to the user.
 */
function getConfig(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  var option1 = config
    .newOptionBuilder()
    .setLabel('Text')
    .setValue('text');

  var option2 = config
    .newOptionBuilder()
    .setLabel('Inline')
    .setValue('inline');

  config
    .newInfo()
    .setId('instructions')
    .setText('Fill out the form to connect to a JSON data source.');

  config
    .newTextInput()
    .setId('url')
    .setName('Enter the URL of a JSON data source')
    .setHelpText('e.g. https://my-url.org/json')
    .setPlaceholder('https://my-url.org/json');

  config
    .newCheckbox()
    .setId('cache')
    .setName('Cache response')
    .setHelpText('Usefull with big datasets. Response is cached for 10 minutes')
    .setAllowOverride(true);

  config
    .newSelectSingle()
    .setId('nestedData')
    .setName('Nested data')
    .setHelpText('How to import nested data, as text or inline.')
    .setAllowOverride(true)
    .addOption(option1)
    .addOption(option2);

  config.setDateRangeRequired(false);

  return config.build();
}

/**
 * Gets UrlFetch response and parses JSON
 *
 * @param   {string} url  The URL to get the data from
 * @returns {Object}      The response object
 */
function fetchJSON(url) {
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  } catch (e) {
    sendUserError('"' + url + '" returned an error:' + e);
  }

  try {
    var content = JSON.parse(response);
  } catch (e) {
    sendUserError('Invalid JSON format. ' + e);
  }

  return content;
}

/**
 * Gets cached response. If the response has not been cached, make
 * the fetchJSON call, then cache and return the response.
 *
 * @param   {string} url  The URL to get the data from
 * @returns {Object}      The response object
 */
function getCachedData(url) {
  var cacheExpTime = 600;
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var cacheKey = url.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '');
  var cacheKeyString = cache.get(cacheKey + '.keys');
  var cacheKeys = cacheKeyString !== null ? cacheKeyString.split(',') : [];
  var cacheData = {};
  var content = [];

  if (cacheKeyString !== null && cacheKeys.length > 0) {
    cacheData = cache.getAll(cacheKeys);

    for (var key in cacheKeys) {
      if (cacheData[cacheKeys[key]] != undefined) {
        content.push(JSON.parse(cacheData[cacheKeys[key]]));
      }
    }
  } else {
    content = fetchJSON(url);

    for (var key in content) {
      cacheData[cacheKey + '.' + key] = JSON.stringify(content[key]);
    }

    cache.putAll(cacheData);
    cache.put(cacheKey + '.keys', Object.keys(cacheData), cacheExpTime);
  }

  return content;
}

/**
 * Fetches data. Either by calling getCachedData or fetchJSON, depending on the cache configuration parameter.
 *
 * @param   {String}  url   The URL to get the data from
 * @param   {Boolean} cache Parameter to determine whether the request should be cached
 * @returns {Object}        The response object
 */
function fetchData(url, cache) {
  if (!url || !url.match(/^https?:\/\/.+$/g)) {
    sendUserError('"' + url + '" is not a valid url.');
  }
  try {
    var content = cache ? getCachedData(url) : fetchJSON(url);
  } catch (e) {
    sendUserError(
      'Your request could not be cached. The rows of your dataset probably exceed the 100KB cache limit.'
    );
  }
  if (!content) sendUserError('"' + url + '" returned no content.');

  return content;
}

/**
 * Matches the field value to a semantic
 *
 * @param   {Mixed}   value   The field value
 * @param   {Object}  types   The list of types
 * @return  {string}          The semantic type
 */
function getSemanticType(value, types) {
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)) {
    return types.NUMBER;
  } else if (value === true || value === false) {
    return types.BOOLEAN;
  } else if (typeof value != 'object' && value != null) {
    if (
      value.match(
        new RegExp(
          /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi
        )
      )
    ) {
      return types.URL;
    } else if (!isNaN(Date.parse(value))) {
      return types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR;
    }
  }
  return types.TEXT;
}

/**
 *  Creates the fields
 *
 * @param   {Object}  fields  The list of fields
 * @param   {Object}  types   The list of types
 * @param   {String}  key     The key value of the current element
 * @param   {Mixed}   value   The value of the current element
 */
function createField(fields, types, key, value) {
  var semanticType = getSemanticType(value, types);
  var field =
    semanticType == types.NUMBER ? fields.newMetric() : fields.newDimension();

  field.setType(semanticType);
  field.setId(key.replace(/\s/g, '_').toLowerCase());
  field.setName(key);
}

/**
 * Handles keys for recursive fields
 *
 * @param   {String}  currentKey  The key value of the current element
 * @param   {Mixed}   key         The key value of the parent element
 * @returns {String}  if true
 */
function getElementKey(key, currentKey) {
  if (currentKey == '' || currentKey == null) {
    return;
  }
  if (key != null) {
    return key + '.' + currentKey.replace('.', '_');
  }
  return currentKey.replace('.', '_');
}

/**
 * Extracts the objects recursive fields and adds it to fields
 *
 * @param   {Object}  fields  The list of fields
 * @param   {Object}  types   The list of types
 * @param   {String}  key     The key value of the current element
 * @param   {Mixed}   value   The value of the current element
 * @param   {boolean} isInline if true
 */
function createFields(fields, types, key, value, isInline) {
  if (typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value) && value !== null) {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(currentKey) {
      var elementKey = getElementKey(key, currentKey);

      if (isInline && value[currentKey] != null) {
        createFields(fields, types, elementKey, value[currentKey], isInline);
      } else {
        createField(fields, types, currentKey, value);
      }
    });
  } else if (key !== null) {
    createField(fields, types, key, value);
  }
}

/**
 * Parses first line of content to determine the data schema
 *
 * @param   {Object}  request getSchema/getData request parameter.
 * @param   {Object}  content The content object
 * @return  {Object}           An object with the connector configuration
 */
function getFields(request, content) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;
  var isInline = request.configParams.nestedData === 'inline';

  if (!Array.isArray(content)) content = [content];

  if (typeof content[0] !== 'object' || content[0] === null) {
    sendUserError('Invalid JSON format');
  }
  try {
    createFields(fields, types, null, content[0], isInline);
  } catch (e) {
    sendUserError('Unable to identify the data format of one of your fields.');
  }
  return fields;
}

/**
 * Returns the schema for the given request.
 *
 * @param   {Object} request Schema request parameters.
 * @returns {Object} Schema for the given request.
 */
function getSchema(request) {
  var content = fetchData(request.configParams.url, request.configParams.cache);
  var fields = getFields(request, content).build();
  return {schema: fields};
}

/**
 * Performs a deep merge of objects and returns new object. Does not modify
 * objects (immutable) and merges arrays via concatenation.
 * Thanks to jhildenbiddle https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903063/jhildenbiddle
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge
 *
 * @param            Objects to merge
 * @returns {object} New object with merged key/values
 */
function mergeDeep() {
  var objects = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return objects.reduce(function(prev, obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      var pVal = prev[key];
      var oVal = obj[key];

      if (Array.isArray(pVal) && Array.isArray(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = pVal.concat.apply(pVal, toConsumableArray(oVal));
      } else if (pVal === Object(pVal) && oVal === Object(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = mergeDeep(pVal, oVal);
      } else {
        prev[key] = oVal;
      }
    });
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

/**
 *  Converts date strings to YYYYMMDDHH:mm:ss
 *
 * @param   {String} val  Date string
 * @returns {String}      Converted date string
 */
function convertDate(val) {
  var date = new Date(val);
  return (
    date.getUTCFullYear() +
    ('0' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    ('0' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
    ('0' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)
  );
}

/**
 * Validates the row values. Only numbers, boolean, date and strings are allowed
 *
 * @param   {Field} field The field declaration
 * @param   {Mixed} val   The value to validate
 * @returns {Mixed}       Either a string or number
 */
function validateValue(field, val) {
  if (field.getType() == 'YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR') {
    val = convertDate(val);
  }

  switch (typeof val) {
    case 'string':
    case 'number':
    case 'boolean':
      return val;
    case 'object':
      return JSON.stringify(val);
  }
  return '';
}

/**
 * Returns the (nested) values for requested columns
 *
 * @param   {Object} valuePaths       Field name. If nested; field name and parent field name
 * @param   {Object} row              Current content row
 * @returns {Mixed}                   The field values for the columns
 */
function getColumnValue(valuePaths, row) {
  for (var index in valuePaths) {
    var currentPath = valuePaths[index];

    if (row[currentPath] === null) {
      return '';
    }

    if (row[currentPath] !== undefined) {
      row = row[currentPath];
      continue;
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(row);

    for (var index_keys in keys) {
      var key = keys[index_keys].replace(/\s/g, '_').toLowerCase();
      if (key == currentPath) {
        row = row[keys[index_keys]];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return row;
}

/**
 * Returns an object containing only the requested columns
 *
 * @param   {Object} content          The content object
 * @param   {Object} requestedFields  Fields requested in the getData request.
 * @returns {Object}                  An object only containing the requested columns.
 */
function getColumns(content, requestedFields) {
  if (!Array.isArray(content)) content = [content];

  return content.map(function(row) {
    var rowValues = [];

    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function(field) {
      var valuePaths = field.getId().split('.');
      var fieldValue = row === null ? '' : getColumnValue(valuePaths, row);

      rowValues.push(validateValue(field, fieldValue));
    });
    return {values: rowValues};
  });
}

/**
 * Returns the tabular data for the given request.
 *
 * @param   {Object} request  Data request parameters.
 * @returns {Object}          Contains the schema and data for the given request.
 */
function getData(request) {
  var content = fetchData(request.configParams.url, request.configParams.cache);
  var fields = getFields(request, content);
  var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var requestedFields = fields.forIds(requestedFieldIds);

  return {
    schema: requestedFields.build(),
    rows: getColumns(content, requestedFields)
  };
}
```

**Step 2**: Deploy your code. After deployment, you get “Deployment id” and direct URL of your Data Source.

**Step 3**: Need to provide your source JSON URL and allow parameters to override by URL. Allow parameters for our need for data according to department wise and connect to the data source.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ys4RCPyWYC8wP31jWtCJcZpqt6SIKnMC/view?usp=sharing

So by using a custom connector, we can show data according to the role.