# Merge child properties of object with another child object

Tags: json, typescript, react-native

I have a json object that looks like below:

```
{
   "client":null,
   "user":{
      "email":"frank55@gmail.com",
      "firstName":"Frank",
      "lastName":"Palto",
      "fullName":"Frank Palto",
      "tags":[
         "Ops",
         "Dev"
      ],
      "hasRegistered": true,
      "url":""
   },
   "user.email":"joseph55@gmail.com",
   "user.firstName":"Joseph",
   "user.lastName":"Enoc",
   "user.mobileNumber":"0123451111"
}
```

I am trying to merge the **user** object with the other user properties outside of the user to create a single unified **user** object that looks like the following:

```
{
   "client":null,
   "user":{
      "email":"joseph55@gmail.com",
      "firstName":"Joseph",
      "lastName":"Enoc",
      "fullName":"Frank Palto",
      "mobileNumber":"0123451111",
      "tags":[
         "Ops",
         "Dev"
      ],
      "hasRegistered": true,
      "url":""
   }
}
```

Notice the merge and how the fields outside user have been put under user and its values has take precedence.

Basically i would like to achieve this without a predefined model. When the JSON is received, we should detect outliers by detecting "user.email" (in the same manner we would a mustache expression) and then perform the merge.

I have looked at other similar solutions but they quite can't provide something a bit more catered to my use case:
[How to merge properties of an object in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007056/how-to-merge-properties-of-an-object-in-an-object)

How best can i achieve this? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to parse the keys using regex and then use the resulting outliers to reassign to the `user` properties using bracket notation. Here's a function that does each part step by step and logs the results (just don't forget to change `fullName` too. I added that to the function as well).

```
function mergeOutliers(yourJSON) {
  console.log('initial JSON\n', yourJSON);
  
  const obj = JSON.parse(yourJSON);
  console.log('resulting object\n', obj);

  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  console.log('all keys\n', keys);

  // could have also been done with key.startsWith('user.');
  const outlierKeys = keys.filter(key => key.match(/.+\..+/));
  console.log('outlier keys\n', outlierKeys);

  const fieldsToReplace = outlierKeys.map(key => key.replace('user.', ''));
  console.log('fields to replace\n', fieldsToReplace);

  for (field of fieldsToReplace) {
    obj.user[field] = obj[`user.${field}`];
    delete obj[`user.${field}`];
  }

  obj.user.fullName = `${obj.user.firstName} ${obj.user.lastName}`;
  console.log('merged object\n', obj);
}
```

Here's a Codepen that tests it out on your JSON string: https://codepen.io/SonicBoomNFA/pen/gOZqgMq