# Dynamically set property of nested object if they exist. Recreate _.extend

Tags: javascript

I am looking to recreate the following as seen below, dynamically without having manually define where the matches are in the Object's properties.

## Desired Outcome

```
const obj = {
  levelOne: {
    someFun: () => {},
    levelTwo: {
      anArray: [],
      something: 'asas',
      levelThree: {
        stay: 'the same',
        name: 'Set this one!',
      },
    },
  },
}

const updatedObj = {
  ...obj,
  levelOne: {
    ...obj.levelOne,
    levelTwo: {
      anArray: [],
      ...obj.levelOne.levelTwo,
      levelThree: {
        ...obj.levelOne.levelTwo.levelThree,
        name: 'Updated prop!',
      },
    },
  },
}

console.info(updatedObj)
{
 levelOne: {
   someFun: () => {},
   levelTwo: {
     something: 'asas',
       levelThree: {
         stay: 'the same',
         name: "Updated prop!",
       },
     },
   },
 }
```

## So far

```
const inputOriginal = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
        something: 'asas',
        levelThree: {
        name: "Original input!"
      }
    }
  }
}
const newInput = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      levelThree: {
        name: "Updated prop!"
      }
    }
  }
}

const mergeObjects = function(overWrite, original){
    return Object.entries(original).reduce( (acc, [ key, item ]) => {
        if(typeof item === 'object' && overWrite[key]) {
            mergeObjects(overWrite[key], item)
            acc = {
                ...acc,
                [key]: item
            }
        } else if(overWrite[key]) {
            acc = {
                ...acc,
                [key]: overWrite[key]
            }
        }
        return acc
    }, {})
}
const merged = mergeObjects(inputOriginal,newInput) //merged.levelOne.levelTwo.levelThree = "Updated prop!"
```

However I can see there is an error logic in my code that, when it comes back out of the recursion, it overwrites the changes values with its self, which has the original values.

How can I create a function that will do the same as 'Desired Outcome'?

Comment: have you had a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty ?

Comment: Ah interesting, so always overwrite it with the new proper inside the last `recursed` item and only if it is not its on property I guess?

Comment: Ok, your question is confusing me, I can see what is the desired outcome, but what should be the desired input? If the desired input is obj and updatedObj, why are they on the desired outcome section? And after executing it, doesn't it do what you already wanted it to do?

Comment: by the way it seems mergeObjects(overWrite[key], item) is doing nothing, because the result isn't being stored anywhere

Comment: Please post some samples of `overWrite` and `original` objects

Comment: I am sorry guys, I have updated the example! Doh

Comment: @Rainb the result is being stored in `merged` For this example just output `merged`

Comment: Rainb is speaking about the mergeObject function called inside of itself. The output of the function has to be stored in the "item" variable: item=mergeObjects(overWrite[key], item). But it's not enough to make your function work.

Comment: How does this differ from any of the other questions about deep merge? Like [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936772/215552)

Comment: Why isn't `anArray` in your updateObj ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this function :

```
const mergeObjects = (obj, updates) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(updates)) {
    if (updates[key] instanceof Object) Object.assign(updates[key], mergeObjects(obj[key], updates[key]))
  }
  Object.assign(obj || {}, updates)
  return obj
}
```

Here is a working example using the given objects :

```js
const inputOriginal = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      something: 'asas',
      levelThree: {
        name: "Original input!"
      }
    }
  }
}
const newInput = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      levelThree: {
        name: "Updated prop!"
      }
    }
  }
}

const mergeObjects = (obj, updates) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(updates)) {
    if (updates[key] instanceof Object) Object.assign(updates[key], mergeObjects(obj[key], updates[key]))
  }
  Object.assign(obj || {}, updates)
  return obj
}

const merged = mergeObjects(inputOriginal, newInput)
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Could I please get a full example :)

Comment: It would be great if this supported functions and arrays Raphael! So thank you for giving me an answer I have awarded you the bounty for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `lodash`

```
_.has(obj, 'l1.l2.l3' ) && _.set(obj, 'l1.l2.l3', 'I am now updated')
```

or

```
_.has(obj, 'l1.l2' ) && _.set(obj, 'l1.l2.l3', 'I am now updated')
```

I guess you can require object sub package only instead of the full lodash

Comment: Thank you, but no thanks :) However I will now check out what has and set do.

Comment: that would be a good idea @JamieHutber I hope their approach would be quite efficient