# Angular ReactiveForm merge Form.Value to object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Folks, I have a massive form built with Angular ReactiveForms including nested array with its own nested array.

In ngOnInit() I fetch data from API:

```
private approval: Approval;

return this.apiService.getApproval(+id).map(data => {
   this.approval = data;
});
```

Next, I patch form:

```
this.form.patchValue(this.approval, { emitEvent: false });
```

and then on SUBMIT call

```
private onSubmit() {

  Object.assign(this.approval, this.form.value);

  return this.apiService.updateApproval(this.approval).map(data => {
  });

}
```

The API I am connecting to requires full object to be POST-ed, not just changes (PATCH is not implemented). Therefore I may not use `this.form.value`, but I have to sent full object.

I am looking for something similar to .NET/C# AutoMapper. The code above - Object.assign - does what I need on first-level properties. Primitive types are updated, however, properties like arrays or objects are ignored.

Is there any recommended 'Angular-way' how to deal with this?
Thanks!

EDIT: it seems like arrays are overwritten. Objects in array have updated values, but some properties from original object, that are not present in Form, are missing.

Comment: `this.approval  = {...this.approval, ...this.form.value}` try this or this `this.approval = Object.assign(this.approval, this.form.value);`

Comment: Object.assign return new object so you have to save that new object so please make it like that `this.approval = Object.assign(this.approval, this.form.value);`

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but no change :(

Comment: Could you log this.approval before send the request

Comment: I did some googling and problem is that Object.assign does only shallow merge. I am going to implement deep merge.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge):

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Have a look at [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge/34749873) for other options too.