# How to use Object.assign to update an nested object

Tags: javascript, object, assign

I want to use `Object.assign` overwrite a nested object within an object.

for example if I have an object like

`let obj = {2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "apple", animal: "cat"}}`

How would I use `Object.assign` to update for example the second object with key `3` to `{fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}` but still maintain the structure of `obj`?

This solution should be dynamic so if for example the next time, the first object with key `2` could be updated to `{fruit: "strawberry", animal: "bat"}`

**EDIT**

So the new returned object will be

`{2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}}`

**EDIT2**

Solution needs to be dynamic

**EDIT3**

Seems as though this can't be achieved with just `Object.assign` so is there a deep copy solution to do this?

Comment: Are you using libraries like Lodash, jQuery or any other library for that matter? Those might have build-in helpers for this kind of deep merging of objects.

Comment: No I'm not using any libraries.

Comment: `obj[3] = {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}; return obj` ... i don't understand the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is not call your object "Object":

```
let obj = {2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "apple", animal: "cat"}};
```

Then you can use `Object.assign()` on `obj[3]`:

```
Object.assign(obj[3], {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"});
```

(If you use "Object" as a variable name, you lose access to the global "Object", making `Object.assign` impossible to use.)

If you want a whole new object, you'll have to make copies of the nested objects because `Object.assign()` performs a *shallow copy* only. In your case that's pretty easy, but in general making a deep copy can be very complicated:

```
let newObj = {
  2: Object.assign({}, obj[2]),
  3: {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}
};
```

Comment: This isn't what I meant but my fault for not making it clear. I want to return a new object with both objects 2 and 3 still in the new object but have object 3 with new values. So this will be the returned object

`{2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}};`

Comment: @Celt67 easy to do, I'll modify the answer

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question. I created an easy example so that it would be easy for other people to understand. Your solution isn't dynamic because what if the next time object `3` needs to be over-ridden and values are  {fruit: "pear", animal: "bat"}? Or if I wanted to update object `2` the next time

Comment: @Celt67 Your example mentions nothing whatsoever about anything being "dynamic". In the general case, what you seem to be asking for is a "deep copy" mechanism, and that gets very complicated. JavaScript has no built-in deep copy, just things like `Object.assign()` and spread syntax for making shallow copies.

Comment: Yeah, my question was very unclear but I thought it was thing you could do by manipulating the `Object.assign` function, just didn't exactly know how. Sounds like you're saying it can't be done using just `Object.assign`. Would it be possible to do up a solution of the deep copy mechanism using this example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
let data = {2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "apple", animal: "cat"}}

Object.assign(data[3], {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: I want the returned object to look like this `{2: {fruit: "orange", animal: "dog"} 3: {fruit: "banana", animal: "pig"}` Apologies, I didn't make that clear in the question.