# Change state without overriding other values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the state of my app without overriding the values that haven't changed. I am doing so using the spread operator, but something is going wrong.

Here is my base state : `useState({data : [{name : undefined , project : []}] });`

With `setState` i want to just add names but keep the project array empty since it didn't change.

```
setManager(prevState => ({...prevState , data : res.data}))
```

After performing setState the new state looks like this :

```
[
    {name: "John doe"},
    {name: "Jane Doe"}
]
```

as you can see the default state is completely overridden.

res.data looks like this by the way :

```
[
  {name: "john doe"},
  {name: "jane doe"}
]
```

Comment: Spread does a shallow merge. See [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936772/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `setManager(prevState => ({...prevState , data : res.data}))` you're simply overriding your earier 'main' `data` property.

`data` is an array, new values are in array ... simply `concat` them

```
setManager(prevState => ({...prevState , 
  data : prevState.data.concat( res.data )
}))
```

After that you should have

```
[  
  {name: undefined , project : []},  
  {name: "john doe"},
  {name: "jane doe"}
]
```

... but probably you wanted to manage names and project separately:

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState({
  data: { 
    name: undefined, 
    project: []
  }
});
```

... or even

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState({
  name: undefined, 
  project: []
});
```

This way you don't need to 'address' this data with 'intermediatory' `.data`

```
<Component names={manager.name} />
```

... not by `{manager.data.name}`.

Of course updating only `name` needs different code

```
setManager(prevState => ({
  ...prevState, 
  name : prevState.name.concat( res.data )
}))
```

- `...prevState` prevents deleting `project` property
- `name` should be initialized with `[]`, not `undefined`
- conditional rendering can be done with `{!manager.name.lenght && ... }

**If you have separate states 'slices' then no need to use one common state, use many `useState` declarations.**

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is:

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState({
  data: [{ name: undefined, project: [] }]
});

setManager(prevState => ({
  data: prevState.data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...res.data[index] }))
}));
```

However, if you're just storing an array of "items", then your state should look more like:

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState([{ name: undefined, project: [] }]);

setManager(prevState =>
  prevState.data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...res.data[index] }))
);
```

Also, the way how you're gonna merge prev and incoming data depends on many things and maybe you need some more sophisticated way of storing state.

Answer (score 1):

You inited your state with **an Array**, not an Object, that's the reason for the behavior.

Change this from

```
useState({data : [{name : undefined , project : []}] });
```

to

```
useState({data : {name : undefined , project : []} });
```