# change state without mutating old state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have this default state :

```
const [manager, setManager] = useState([{ name: undefined, project: [] }]);
```

I have data coming from an API that looks like this :

```
[{name : 'John doe'} , {'jane' : doe}]
```

How do i update my state so it ends up looking like this after adding the data to the state :

```
[{ name: 'john doe', project: [] } , { name: 'jane doe', project: [] }];
```

I tried this :

```
setManager(prev => ([...prev , res.data]));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change state without overriding other values in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930779/change-state-without-overriding-other-values-in-react)

Comment: Haven't you already accepted the answer to your very same question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you want to change this:

```
[{name : 'John doe'}, {name : 'Jane doe'}]
```

to something like this

```
[{ name: 'john doe', project: [] } , { name: 'jane doe', project: [] }];
```

In this snippet, you are spreading the existing data with the new data.

```
 setManager(prev => ([...prev, res.data]));
```

So in `manager`, you will get 2 arrays because you didn't spread the second one

```
[{ name: undefined, project: [] }, [{name : 'John doe'} , {name : 'Jane doe'}]]
```

In this case, also making the assumptions that your `project` key might not be empty, and you want to `map` the existing project with data inside each your api data.

I will do something like this

```
setManager(prevData => 
  resData.map(singleRes => {
    return {name: singleRes.name, project: prevData.project}
  })
)
```