# Merging two objects with same keys override first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I would like to merge an array with another array. The only catch is that each array is within an object.

Intuitively I tried `{...arrObj, ...newArrObj}` however this leads `newArrObj` overwriting items in the `arrObj`.

```js
const array = ['an', 'array'];
const newArray = [, , 'new', 'ehrray'];

const obj = {
  key: { ...array
  }
};

const newObj = {
  key: { ...newArray
  }
};

const merged = { ...obj,
  ...newObj
};

console.log(merged);
```

I would expect `merged` to be:

```js
{
  "key": {
    "0": "an",
    "1": "array",
    "2": "new",
    "3": "ehrray"
  }
}
```

but receive

```js
{
  "key": {
    "2": "new",
    "3": "ehrray"
  }
}
```

Comment: The merge logic you want to use is not clear. Why *wouldn't* the `null` override the values of `array`? What do you expect to happen to them? Disappear? What would you expect to have happen when there are actual strings instead of `null` in the first two values?

Comment: `merged = { key: { ...newArray, ...array } };` works for your specific example, but the task itself feels weird; maybe an XY problem? What's the purpose/context of this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The idea is that there are unset values with only a few set. eg. `const newArray = new Array(4); newArray[2] = 'new';`

Comment: "unset" means that no value is set. In the example the `newArray` indexes `0` and `1` are both set to `null`. For an array with 2 unset indexes use `[ , , 'new', 'ehrray']` which is an array of length 4 from which the first two indexes are not present. `"0" in newArray` would result in `false`.

Comment: 3limin4t0r good call out. I used `null` to denote `unset`. However, defining `newArray = [ , , 'new', 'ehrray']` does seem to produce the same outcome, simply without the null values.

Comment: @LoganC the spread syntax is very powerfull and expressive in a very limited way. It does create a shallow merge, not a deep one, so `merged = { ...obj, ...newObj };` should rather be: `merged = { ...obj, ...newObj, key: { ...obj.key, ...newObj.key } }`. The way you deep-merge two objects can vary a lot depending on what you're trying to express with that merge, therefore there's no built-in solution for that. Some libraries have implemented a deep-merge function, but they always express the developers opinion on how you're supposed to merge two objects; That may not always be what you want.

Comment: Got it, thanks Thomas. I think this is likely what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful

```js
const a0 = ['1', '2', undefined , undefined, '5', '6', '7'];
const a1 = [undefined, undefined, '3', '4'];

function merge(a, b) {
  return a.map(function(v,i){ return v?v:b[i]});
}

console.log(a0 > a1?merge(a0, a1):merge(a1, a0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to updated that I ended up going with a [recursive merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001459/1466936) to get the nested object containing an array merged.

```js
const array = ['an', 'array'];
const newArray = [, , 'new', 'ehrray'];

const obj = {
  key: { ...array
  }
};

const newObj = {
  key: { ...newArray
  }
};

const merge = (obj1, obj2) => {

  const recursiveMerge = (obj, entries) => {
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        obj[key] = obj[key] ? { ...obj[key]
        } : {};
        recursiveMerge(obj[key], Object.entries(value))
      } else {
        obj[key] = value;
      }
    }

    return obj;
  }

  return recursiveMerge(obj1, Object.entries(obj2))
}

console.log(merge(obj, newObj));
```

Answer (score -1):

> The idea is that there are unset values with only a few set. eg. `const newArray = new Array(4); newArray[2] = 'new'`;

`{ value: null }`, even `{ value: undefined }` is not the same thing as `{ foo: 42 }` with no `value` at all. That's the reason that in your example `"an"` and `"array"` are overwritten with the `null`s from the `newArray`.

This particular example you can solve by swapping the order in which you add the arrays to the result, but as soon as both arrays contain `null`-values there is no way to do it with spread-syntax / `Object.assign` alone. You have to implement the behaviour:

```js
const array = new Array('an', 'array', null, null, "and", "more", "from", "array");
const newArray = new Array(null, null, 'new', 'ehrray');

function merge(a, b) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length || i < b.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = b[i] == null ? a[i] : b[i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(merge(array, newArray));
```