# how to insert deep in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object with tables:

```
let tables = {
  "2021-08-25": {
    "B0705": {
      "48": "heaven"
    },
    "B0704": {
      "48": "hell"
    }
  }
}
```

An I would like to insert dynamicly a new table.
I tried this:

```
var insertTable = (date,table,slot) => {
  let newDesk = {
      [date]: {
        [table]: {
          [slot]: 'slotter'
        }
      }
  };
  Object.assign(tables,newDesk);
};
```

But it overwrites my exsiting entrances.

This will also not work:

```
  var insertTable2 = (date,table,slot) => {
    Object.defineProperty(tables, date, {
      table: {slot: 'slotter'}
    });
  };
```

How this will work?

```
insertTable2("2021-08-25","B0705","22");
insertTable2("2021-08-25","B0705","12");
insertTable2("2021-08-25","B0706","33");
insertTable2("2021-08-26","B0703","11");
```

Comment: just create a new table as insertTable as you would like and combine them with tables = {...tables, ...insertTable} object destructuring is what you would like to search for

Comment: Though the question is trivial, its title is sure to drive traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more reusable solution, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27936772/3083470) - you want to deep merge the new object with the old one, not shallowly merge them.

A non reusable solution can be built like this (to illustrate that for more complex paths/requirements the above solution is much easier):

```js
let tables = {
  "2021-08-25": {
    "B0705": {
      "48": "heaven"
    },
    "B0704": {
      "48": "hell"
    }
  }
}
// this will mutate the tables object
const insertTable = (date, table, slot) => {
  // is there an object with this date yet? if not create it.
  if(typeof tables[date] === "undefined"){
    tables[date] = {};
  }
  // is there an object with this table yet? if not create it.
  if(typeof tables[date][table] === "undefined"){
    tables[date][table] = {};
  }
  // set the value now that we know all intermediate objects are defined.
  tables[date][table][slot] = "slotter";
  
  
}
console.log(tables);
insertTable("2021-08-25","B0705","22");
insertTable("2021-08-25","B0705","12");
insertTable("2021-08-25","B0706","33");
insertTable("2021-08-26","B0703","11");

console.log(tables);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array to express the object path you wish the value to be placed at, also specifying the value to be set at the path.

We'd then use `Array.reduce()` to navigate down the path and eventually set the `value` at the last path element:

```js
let tables = {
  "2021-08-25": {
    "B0705": {
      "48": "heaven"
    },
    "B0704": {
      "48": "hell"
    }
  }
}

function insertTable(table, path, value) {
    path.reduce((acc, pathElement, idx) => {
        if (idx < path.length -1) {
            // We're not at the final element of path, add a new object if necessary
            if (!acc[pathElement]) acc[pathElement] = {};
        } else {
            // We're at the last pathElement, set the value, e.g. 'slotter'
            acc[pathElement] = value;
        }
        return acc[pathElement];
    }, table)
}

insertTable(tables, ['2021-08-25', 'B0705', '22'], 'slotter');
insertTable(tables, ['2021-08-25', 'B0705', '12'], 'slotter');
insertTable(tables, ['2021-08-25', 'B0706', '33'], 'some value');
insertTable(tables, ['2021-08-26', 'B0703', '11'], 'another value');

console.log(tables)
```