# Javascript overwrite part of a nested object with object merging

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a JS project where I need to override some values in my object which contains nested objects.

I'd normally use the following:

```js
const merged = { ...application, ...customer }
```

So that any data inside of `customer` can override the `application`.

However, in my example, `customer` is overriding the entire `applicant` nested object and I just need to override the name within that object?

I've put together a JS fiddle which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xueqzar9/), what am I missing?

```js
const customer = {
  applicant: {
    first_name: 'john'
  }
}

const application = {
  applicant: {
    first_name: 'edward',
    age: 50
  },
  income: {
    salary: 500
  }
}

const merged = { ...application, ...customer }

console.log(merged)
```

In `merged` I expect the `first_name` to be "John" whilst everything else remains in tact.

Comment: *what am I missing?* - that it's not a recursive operation. `...application` takes the fields of `application`, so `applicant` and `income`, then `...customer` overwrites `applicant` with its own field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Answer (score 1):

The properties you want to replace via spreading have to be at the top level of the object.  In this case you take the top-level properties of application, which are applicant and income, and then replace the applicant property with that from customer.  If you want the name to be replaced you would need something like

```
const merged = {
  ...application, 
  applicant: {...application.applicant, ...customer.applicant}
};
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error of `Unexpected token`

Comment: I put curly braces in wrong spot, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with lodash

```
const merged = _.merge(customer, application)
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge

Comment: I get that lodash has a lot of useful utility methods, but the OP neither mentioned or asked for a lodash solution