# Javascript - Merge object while adding new fields to nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```
const config = {
  name: "app",
  android: {
    name: "app-android",
    googleMaps: {
      location: "us",
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to create a new object `dynamicConfig`, which copies the `config` object but adding some fields to `android.googleMaps`:

```
const dynamicConfig = {
  ...config,
  android: {
    ...config.android,
    googleMaps: {
      ...config.android.googleMaps,
      endPoint: "some-endpoint",
      apiKey: "some-api-key",
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other cleaner way to handle this? Do I have to spread multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is how to do **Deep Merge**, which I highly suggest you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge) out first.

So, you will now see that there are, unfortunately, 2 main options for you.

1. Write your own deep merge function
2. Use external library because, yes, others have done that already

In case you need the library, I suggest you try [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) [_.merge()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge).

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this. [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) creates a deep clone of a given value

```
const dynamicConfig = structuredClone(config);
dynamicConfig.android.googleMaps.endPoint = "some-endpoint";
dynamicConfig.android.googleMaps.apiKey= "some-api-key";
```

Comment: Have to note that this is not a language feature though. Depends on the runtime environment whether or not this function will be available.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Lodash Merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge), it is the easiest way to deep merge. For example:

```
var merge = require('lodash.merge');

const config = {
name: "app",
android: {
    name: "app-android",
    googleMaps: {
            location: "us",
        }
    }
}

const additionalConfig = {
android: {
    googleMaps: {
        endPoint: "some-endpoint",
        apiKey: "some-api-key",
      }
   }
}

output = merge(config, additionalConfig);
console.log(output);
```

Result:

```
{
name: "app",
android: {
    name: "app-android",
    googleMaps: {
        apiKey: "some-api-key",
        endPoint: "some-endpoint",
        location: "us",
    }
}
```

}