# whitelist nested item in state (Redux persist)

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux-persist

The state in my reducer contains the key `current_theme`, which contains an object, with the key `palette`, which contains an object with the key `mode` which can either be the string value "dark" or the string value "light"

So I need to make only this bit of data persistent while leaving all other attributes intact.

redux-persist offers a whitelist parameter which is what I want. However, I can only do something like

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer (
    {
        key: 'theme',
        storage,
        whitelist: ["current_theme"]
    },
    myReducer
);
```

But this makes everything inside `current_theme` persistent. I want only `current_theme.palette.mode` to be persistent and nothing else.

I tried the below but it didn't work neither

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer (
    {
        key: 'theme',
        storage,
        whitelist: ["current_theme.palette.mode"]
    },
    myReducer
);
```

Comment: According to the documentation : "blacklist and whitelist only work one level deep, but we can use a nested persist to blacklist a deeper value". Take a look at [Nested Persists](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists).

Comment: @Tom Oh, that sucks. I can't use that nested persist approach because my reducer has to be defined on top-level :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write my own simplified code for a `persistReducer` method which allows nested blacklisting/whitelisting with the help of [dot-prop-immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-prop-immutable) and the deep merge function in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge). thanks to [Salakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938161/salakar) and [CpILL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196732/cpill)

```
import dotProp from "dot-prop-immutable";

const STORAGE_PREFIX: string = 'persist:';

interface persistConfig {
    key: string;
    whitelist?: string[];
    blacklist?: string[];
}

function isObject(item:any) {
    return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

function mergeDeep(target:any, source:any) {
    let output = Object.assign({}, target);
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
            if (isObject(source[key])) {
                if (!(key in target))
                    Object.assign(output, { [key]: source[key] });
                else
                    output[key] = mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
            } else {
                Object.assign(output, { [key]: source[key] });
            }
        });
    }
    return output;
}

function filterState({ state, whitelist, blacklist }: { state: any, whitelist?: string[], blacklist?: string[] }) {
    if (whitelist && blacklist) {
        throw Error("Can't set both whitelist and blacklist at the same time");
    }
    if (whitelist) {
        var newState: any = {};
        for (const i in whitelist) {
            let val = dotProp.get(state, whitelist[i]);
            if (val !== undefined) {
                newState = dotProp.set(newState, whitelist[i], val)
            }
        }
        return newState;
    }
    if (blacklist) {
        var filteredState: any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
        for (const i in blacklist) {
            filteredState = dotProp.delete(filteredState, blacklist[i]);
        }
        return filteredState;
    }
    return state
}

export function persistReducer(config: persistConfig, reducer: any) {
    const { key, whitelist, blacklist } = config;
    var restore_complete = false;
    return (state: any, action: { type: string, payload?: any }) => {
        const newState = reducer(state, action)
        if (action.type === '@@INIT' && !restore_complete) {
            restore_complete = true;
            const data = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_PREFIX + key);
            if (data !== null) {
                const newData = mergeDeep(newState, JSON.parse(data));
                console.log("Restoring data:", data ,"\nnewData: ", newData);
                return newData;
            }
        }
        if(restore_complete){
            const filteredNewState = filterState({
                state: newState,
                whitelist,
                blacklist
            })
            localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_PREFIX + key, JSON.stringify(filteredNewState));
        }
        return newState;
    }
}
```

### Usage:

Same as the persistReducer function in redux-persist except that no storage options. it always uses localStorage and it accepts dotted paths in both the whitelist and blacklist parameters

if you do something like:

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer (
    {
        key: 'theme',
        whitelist: ["current_theme.palette.mode"]
    },
    myReducer
);
```

Then `current_theme.palette.mode` would always be saved permanently. While any other props in the store, under current_theme, or under palette will remain intact.

**Note:** All you have to do to use this state persistence code is to pass your reducer function through the `persistReducer`. No additional configurations such as creating a persister, from the store and wrapping your app in a PersistGate. No need to install any packages other than dot-prop-immutable, Just use the persistedReducer of your original reducer as returned by `persistReducer` and you're good to go.

**Note:** If a default value is provided to your original reducer and some state has been saved from a previous session, both will be deeply merged when while the initial state is being loaded, with the persisted state from the previous session having higher priority so it can overwrite default values.