html canvas isometric tile map rendering
am trying to achieve something like this

but i always endup tiles are not rendering when reaching to boundries , it should be drawing 200x200 map how ever it only show 17x17
the game am building is similer in idea to travian kingdoms but whole different story and design
here is the code


const canvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const tileWidth = 128; // Tile width
const tileHeight = 64; // Tile height
const gridSize = 1000; // Large grid size for 1,000,000 tiles (1000x1000)
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let offsetX = canvas.width / 2; // Start with center offset
let offsetY = canvas.height / 2; // Start with center offset
let isDragging = false;
let startX, startY;

// Test data for tiles using colors
const testData = [
  '#76b041', // Grass
  '#557a29', // Forest
  '#c2b280', // Plain
  '#a4a4a4', // Mountain
];

function drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(screenX, screenY);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX + tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX, screenY + tileHeight);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX - tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // Optional: add border to each tile
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw the coordinates on the tile
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.font = '14px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText(`(${x}, ${y})`, screenX, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
}

function loadMap() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas

  // Calculate how many tiles we need to draw to cover the screen
  const tilesX = Math.ceil(canvas.width / tileWidth) + 2;
  const tilesY = Math.ceil(canvas.height / tileHeight) + 2;

  for (let x = -tilesX; x <= tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = -tilesY; y <= tilesY; y++) {
      // Convert grid coordinates to screen coordinates
      const screenX = (x - y) * (tileWidth / 2) + offsetX;
      const screenY = (x + y) * (tileHeight / 2) + offsetY;

      // Draw the tile
      const tileColor = testData[(x + y + gridSize) % testData.length];
      drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, tileColor);
    }
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e) {
  isDragging = true;
  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDragging) return;

  const dx = e.clientX - startX;
  const dy = e.clientY - startY;

  offsetX += dx;
  offsetY += dy;

  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;

  loadMap(); // Redraw the map based on the new position
}

function onMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
}

// Initial load
loadMap();

// Handle window resizing
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  loadMap();
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
<canvas id="mapCanvas"></canvas>




your help is appreciated thank you in advance
i tried every possible solution with no hope

The map size depends on the viewport size and the tile size. Why you don't enlarge the viewport or reduce the tiles?

Its the game mechanics 200x200 map

The values tilesX and tilesY determine how many tiles cover the scrolled canvas but not the screen.

Could u please post a full answer that allow to draw new tiles while dragging the map

An optimized drawing of the whole map:
function loadMap() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas

    for (let x = -200; x <= 200; x++) {
        for (let y = -200; y <= 200; y++) {
            // Convert grid coordinates to screen coordinates
            const screenX = (x - y) * (tileWidth / 2) + offsetX;
            const screenY = (x + y) * (tileHeight / 2) + offsetY;
            if (screenX >= -tileWidth && screenX < canvas.width &&
                screenY >= -tileHeight && screenY < canvas.height) {
                // Draw the tile
                const tileColor = testData[(x + y + gridSize) % testData.length];
                drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, tileColor);
            }
        }
    }
}


The number of tiles to draw should not be computed.
Also, don't render the tiles that are not visible. This will improve performance.
In the code below, I chose a fixed number of tiles to draw i.e. 64x64, but you could change this to 200x200. I chose a smaller number for demonstration.
const tilesX = 32, tilesY = 32; // Number of tiles to draw

// Check to see if the tile would be visible in the viewport
function isDrawable(x, y, width, height) {
  return x > -width  &&
         x < ctx.canvas.width + width &&
         y > -height &&
         y < ctx.canvas.height + height
}

function drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, color) {
  // Skip the drawing of the tile, if not visible
  if (!isDrawable(screenX, screenY, tileWidth, tileHeight)) return;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(screenX, screenY);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX + tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX, screenY + tileHeight);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX - tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // Optional: add border to each tile
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw the coordinates on the tile
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.font = '8px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText(`(${x}, ${y})`, screenX, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
}

Demo


const canvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const tilesX = 32, tilesY = 32; // Number of tiles to draw

const tileWidth = 64; // Tile width
const tileHeight = 32; // Tile height
const gridSize = 1000; // Large grid size for 1,000,000 tiles (1000x1000)
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let offsetX = canvas.width / 2; // Start with center offset
let offsetY = canvas.height / 2; // Start with center offset
let isDragging = false;
let startX, startY;

// Test data for tiles using colors
const testData = [
  '#76b041', // Grass
  '#557a29', // Forest
  '#c2b280', // Plain
  '#a4a4a4', // Mountain
];

// Check to see if the tile would be visible in the viewport
function isDrawable(x, y, width, height) {
  return x > -width  &&
         x < ctx.canvas.width + width &&
         y > -height &&
         y < ctx.canvas.height + height
}

function drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, color) {
  // Skip the drawing of the tile, if not visible
  if (!isDrawable(screenX, screenY, tileWidth, tileHeight)) return;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(screenX, screenY);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX + tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX, screenY + tileHeight);
  ctx.lineTo(screenX - tileWidth / 2, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // Optional: add border to each tile
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw the coordinates on the tile
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.font = '8px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText(`(${x}, ${y})`, screenX, screenY + tileHeight / 2);
}

function loadMap() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas

  for (let x = -tilesX; x <= tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = -tilesY; y <= tilesY; y++) {
      // Convert grid coordinates to screen coordinates
      const screenX = (x - y) * (tileWidth / 2) + offsetX;
      const screenY = (x + y) * (tileHeight / 2) + offsetY;
      
      // Draw the tile
      const tileColor = testData[(x + y + gridSize) % testData.length];
      drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, tileColor);
    }
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e) {
  isDragging = true;
  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDragging) return;

  const dx = e.clientX - startX;
  const dy = e.clientY - startY;

  offsetX += dx;
  offsetY += dy;

  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;

  loadMap(); // Redraw the map based on the new position
}

function onMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
}

// Initial load
loadMap();

// Handle window resizing
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  loadMap();
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
<canvas id="mapCanvas"></canvas>



To draw a red border around the entire map, you can do this.
I organized the code into a reusable class. But keep in mind that your render method should not be computing anything. You should have a separate update method that interpolates movements.


function main() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('#map-canvas').getContext('2d');
  const tileMap = new TileMap(ctx, {
    dimensions: { x: 3, y: 3 },
    tileSize: { width: 128, height: 64 }
  });
}

// Test data for tiles using colors
const testData = [
  '#76b041', // Grass
  '#557a29', // Forest
  '#c2b280', // Plain
  '#a4a4a4', // Mountain
];

class TileMap {
  constructor(ctx, options = {}) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

    const opts = mergeDeep({}, TileMap.defaultOptions, options);
    this.tilesX = opts.dimensions.x;
    this.tilesY = opts.dimensions.y;
    this.tileWidth = opts.tileSize.width;
    this.tileHeight = opts.tileSize.height;

    this.init();
    this.render();
  }
  init() {
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.startX = 0;
    this.startY = 0;

    this.resize();

    // Set origin
    this.offsetX = this.ctx.canvas.width / 2;
    this.offsetY = this.ctx.canvas.height / 2 - this.tileHeight / 2;

    this._addListeners();
  }
  destroy() {
    this._removeListeners();
  }
  resize() {
    this.ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  _addListeners() {
    this.onMouseDown = this._onMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.onMouseMove = this._onMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.onMouseUp = this._onMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.onResize = this._onResize.bind(this);

    this.ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
    this.ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);

    window.addEventListener('resize', this._onResize);
  }
  _removeListeners() {
    this.ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
    this.ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);

    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  }
  _onResize = () => {
    this.resize();
    this.render();
  }
  _onMouseDown(e) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.startX = e.clientX;
    this.startY = e.clientY;
  }
  _onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.isDragging) return;

    const dx = e.clientX - this.startX;
    const dy = e.clientY - this.startY;

    this.offsetX += dx;
    this.offsetY += dy;

    this.startX = e.clientX;
    this.startY = e.clientY;

    this.render();
  }
  _onMouseUp() {
    this.isDragging = false;
  }
  render() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height);
    for (let x = -this.tilesX; x <= this.tilesX; x++) {
      for (let y = -this.tilesY; y <= this.tilesY; y++) {
        // Convert grid coordinates to screen coordinates
        const screenX = (x - y) * (this.tileWidth / 2) + this.offsetX;
        const screenY = (x + y) * (this.tileHeight / 2) + this.offsetY;

        // Draw the tile
        const tileColor = testData[(x + y + 100) % testData.length];
        this._drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, tileColor);
      }
    }

    // Draw a red border around the entire tilemap
    this._drawBorder();
  }
  _drawPoly(polygon) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    let p = polygon[0];
    this.ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    for (let i = 1; i < polygon.length; i++) {
      p = polygon[i];
      this.ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    }
    this.ctx.closePath();
  }
  _drawBorder() {
    this._drawPoly([{
      x: -this.tilesX * this.tileWidth + this.offsetX - this.tileWidth/2,
      y: this.offsetY + this.tileHeight/2
    }, {
      x: this.offsetX,
      y: -this.tilesY * this.tileHeight + this.offsetY
    }, {
      x: this.tilesX * this.tileWidth + this.offsetX + this.tileWidth/2,
      y: this.offsetY + this.tileHeight/2
    }, {
      x: this.offsetX,
      y: this.tilesY * this.tileHeight + this.offsetY + this.tileHeight
    }]);
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#F00';
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
  _drawTile(x, y, screenX, screenY, color) {
    if (!this._isDrawable(screenX, screenY)) return;

    const ty = this.tileHeight / 2;
    const tx = this.tileWidth / 2;

    this._drawPoly([
      { x: screenX, y: screenY },
      { x: screenX + tx, y: screenY + ty },
      { x: screenX, y: screenY + this.tileHeight },
      { x: screenX - tx, y: screenY + ty },
    ]);

    this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    this.ctx.stroke();

    // Draw the coordinates on the tile
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    this.ctx.font = Math.floor(this.tileHeight * 0.25) + 'px monospace';
    this.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    this.ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    this.ctx.fillText(`(${x}, ${y})`, screenX, screenY + ty);
  }
  _isDrawable(screenX, screenY) {
    return screenX > -this.tileWidth &&
           screenX < this.ctx.canvas.width + this.tileWidth &&
           screenY > -this.tileHeight &&
           screenY < this.ctx.canvas.height + this.tileHeight
  }
}
TileMap.defaultOptions = {
  dimensions: { x: 8, y: 8 },
  tileSize: { width: 64, height: 32 }
};

// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218209/1762224
function mergeDeep(...objects) {
  const isObject = obj => obj && typeof obj === 'object';
  return objects.reduce((prev, obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      const pVal = prev[key], oVal = obj[key];
      if (Array.isArray(pVal) && Array.isArray(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = pVal.concat(...oVal);
      } else if (isObject(pVal) && isObject(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = mergeDeep(pVal, oVal);
      } else {
        prev[key] = oVal;
      }
    });
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

main();
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: #222;
}
<canvas id="map-canvas"></canvas>




everything working thank you so much , just one more thing i want it when it reach the end it gives a red border then start showing the opposite side of the map so it will be infinity scroll but showing red border at the edge to identify that it reached the end

can you please help me fix this issue
