# Alternative to formData() function in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, form-data

I am using following code to upload photo to facebook with ajax:

```
function _upCover(id, imgURL) {
    $('#uploadb').hide(0);
     imgURL ="myimageurl.jpg"  

     var postMSG= "my test";
 var url='https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='+accessToken+"&message="+postMSG;

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('url',imgURL);

  $.ajax({          type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType:  false,
                    processData: false,

                    success: function(data){  
                                                 uploads(id);   },

                    error: function(data){
                                              failed(id);       }
                });


}
```

This works fine in Firefox but not in other browsers because it uses `FormData()` function. Is there any way to do it without using `FormData()` so it works in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution: [How to get form data as a object in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403179/how-to-get-form-data-as-a-object-in-jquery)
Besides, FormData() should be supported not only in Mozilla, but also in Chrome and Safari 5+.

Comment: But its not supported by IE 7,8 and 9. Which always seems to be the issue

Comment: very little browser compatibility according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get