# How to get and replace data from form serialize() before submitting?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I need to submit a form using jQuery but before it's submitted I want to change the value of one of the form fields *without* showing the change to the user. I know it's not the best way but my software demands that.

Currently I use:

```
var submit = $("#submitform").serialize();
```

To serialize data and then submit them using

```
$.post('/post', submit)
```

The serialized data I have are:

```
entry%5Bbody%5D=hello+and+welcome&addedContexts=presentation&context=prese ntation&selectedContexts=&statementid=&timestamp=
```

I simply want to change the value of `entry%5Bbody%5D` to something else.

I know I could use Regex on the string (I can't find which?), but maybe you know of a more elegant solution? Such as first serializing the form, then deserializing it, changing the value I need, and serializing it again?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403179/how-to-get-form-data-as-a-object-in-jquery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`$("#submitform").serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and search for the item in the array with the `name` property equal to `"entry[body]"` and edit its `value` property.

```
// convert form data to array
var data = $("#submitform").serializeArray();

// edit data here
// using ES6
data.find(item => item.name === 'entry[body]').value = "something else";
// OR using ES5
data.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item.name === 'entry[body]') {
    item.value = "something else";
  }
});

// then POST
$.post('/post', $.param(data));
```

Comment: Ok, but then how do I assemble the object I get with `serializeArray` back into the string?